# System Views text in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, system

I am looking for viewing the text of the system views and procedures in SQL Server 2005 using the object explorer or using sp_helptext.

actually i am coming from the SQL Server 2000 background, where we have the feature of retreiving the code of the view and the stored procedure using SQL Server 2000 Enterprise manager directly, but still i am unable to find this feature in the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and still looking for the same feature for getting the view and procedure text in SQL Server 2005.

Kindly please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to SQL Server Management Studio? It is now sys.sp_helptext and can be browsed at master --> Programmability --> Stored Procedures --> System Stored Procedures in the object browser and executed with

```
exec sys.sp_helptext ObjectName
```

All the information you are looking for can be found in the [syscomments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293(SQL.90).aspx) table which stores the definitions of all views, rules, defaults, triggers, CHECK constraints, DEFAULT constraints, and stored procedures. The SQL definition statements are stored in the "text" column.

```
select text from syscomments  where id =
OBJECT_id('objectname')
order by colid
```

Comment: thank you for your comments, and again i am asking you the same question in case of views, please let me know how to get the view text in SQL Server 2005.

here i am again looking for the text of the system views as present in the SQL Server 2005 Master database.

Comment: The same query will for with views, procs, functions, etc. e.g.
select text from master..syscomments 
where id = object_id('information_schema.columns')

Comment: But Friend, 
it is like using the query analyzer and the sp_helptext command in SQL Server 2000, but how to achieve the same thing using the SQL Server 2005 Enterprise manager, as we can easily do that for views in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise manager, hope i am clear on this and 
thanks for the query

Comment: I see what you mean now, I just tried to right click and script a system view. Sorry I was not of more assistance. I'll share if I find anything further.

Answer (score 1):

[This Stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181909/tool-for-scripting-table-data#181942) has a database reverse engineering script that (amongst other things) reverse engineers view definitions.  From the script

```
-- This generates view definitions 
--
select definition + char(10) + 'go' + char(10)
  from sys.sql_modules c
  join sys.objects o
    on c.object_id = o.object_id
  join #views o2
    on o.object_id = o2.object_id
```

Note that `#views` is populated earlier in the script with a list of views to dump out.  To select for a particular schema (also from the script)

```
select o.name
      ,o.object_id
  into #views
  from sys.objects o
  join sys.schemas s
    on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
 where o.type in  ('V')
   and s.name = @schema
```

To get stored procedures, substitute 'P'; to get functions substitute 'FN' or 'TF'

In the `master` database the definitions for the system stored procedures live in `sys.system_views`, 'sys.system_objects`, 'sys.system_columns`, and `sys.system_sql_modules`.  The queries in the reverse engineering script could be adapted fairly readily to get out the definitions of the system items by using these tables.

Comment: Is the information in syscomments volatile in such a way that it is inadvisable to just retrieve the definition?

Comment: Probably not, but syscomments is a backwards compatilbility feature for SQL2000 and may or may not last indefinitely (in practice it will probably be around for a while yet).  Also, the OP seems to after the definitions of the system sprocs and views, which live in a different set of tables.

Comment: Syscomments shouldn't be used because it only shows 8000-byte chunks of the source text. Then you have to string them together or do something else to handle the chunks intelligently.

Comment: @ErikE - it's fairly straightforward to use a recursive CTE to concatenate the chunks from syscomments

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells Of course! But why would you do that if you can just use `sys.system_sql_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the text that defines a procedure:

Right click the stored procedure, and choose Modify.  This will show the SQL that defines the stored procedure.

Or: right click, Script Stored Procedure as, CREATE To, New Query Editor Window.

The other answers are more advanced but I thought maybe you were asking a simple question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to list all the Dynamic Management Views:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects
WHERE name LIKE 'dm_%'
order by name
```

Unfortunately, if you run sp_helptext on these it doesn't give you much. For example,

```
exec sp_helptext   N'sys.dm_os_sys_info'
```

Returns:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.dm_os_sys_info AS
    SELECT *
    FROM OpenRowset(TABLE SYSINFO)
```

All the ones I tried gave the same result.