# how to see/script definitions of system views?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, view, system

I tried to execute scripts from [1] in model database and user-defined databases but they give definitions/scripts of only user-defined (non-system) views, i.e. those that I anyway can easily get from GUI.

How can I see/script the definition/script of a system view in SQL Server 2008 R2?

[1]
Answers to question "System Views text in SQL Server 2005"
[System Views text in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432500/system-views-text-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select object_definition(object_id('[sys].[server_permissions]')) 
      AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

(The XML bit is just to prevent long definitions getting truncated when viewed in SSMS)

You can also stop the SQL Server instance. Copy the `mssqlsystemresource` file (on my system this is at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\Binn\mssqlsystemresource.mdf and then re-attatch the copy under a new name).

In the reattached version it is easier to poke around and see the various definitions using normal SSMS functionality.

Comment: thanks for answer! Please see my follow-up questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877923/questions-on-copying-nonsystem-nonused-sql-server-database