# What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, code-generation

We are writing a new application, and while testing, we will need a bunch of dummy data. I've added that data by using MS Access to dump excel files into the relevant tables.

Every so often, we want to "refresh" the relevant tables, which means dropping them all, re-creating them, and running a saved MS Access append query.

The first part (dropping & re-creating) is an easy sql script, but the last part makes me cringe. I want a single setup script that has a bunch of INSERTs to regenerate the dummy data.

I have the data in the tables now. What is the best way to automatically generate a big list of INSERT statements from that dataset?

The only way I can think of doing it is to save the table to an excel sheet and then write an excel formula to create an INSERT for every row, which is surely not the best way.

I'm using the 2008 Management Studio to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database.

Comment: Wow, I just checked on my installation and, you're right, the "script table as" -> "INSERT" only gives you a insert template, not a page of inserts with your actual data! I hope your question gets answered because I'd like an easy way to do what you're asking too.

Comment: @JosephStyons I've updated the question a bit in an attempt to massively simplify and clarify it, and keep it relevant. This has become a seminal question on StackOverflow, and it would be nice to keep the workload down on people who are coming here for a solution. =) See if you find any of the removed information important. If you have any objections about the edit feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thank you Evan.  I did roll it back; I respectfully suggest that some of the background information is useful not only for context, but also for helping the question come up with real world search terms.  I did keep one of your changes; I left out the paragraph regarding Toad for Oracle.  That's probably not very helpful.

Comment: I use SSMSBoost. https://www.ssmsboost.com

Answer (score 1302, accepted):

Microsoft should advertise this functionality of SSMS 2008. The feature you are looking for is built into the **Generate Script** utility, but the functionality is turned off by default and must be enabled when scripting a table.

This is a quick run through to generate the `INSERT` statements for all of the data in your table, using no scripts or add-ins to SQL Management Studio 2008:

1. Right-click on the database and go to **Tasks** > **Generate Scripts**.
2. Select the tables (or objects) that you want to generate the script against.
3. Go to **Set scripting options** tab and click on the **Advanced** button.
4. In the **General** category, go to **Type of data to script**
5. There are 3 options: **Schema Only**, **Data Only**, and **Schema and Data**. Select the appropriate option and click on **OK**.
   [image: SqlDataOptions]

You will then get the `CREATE TABLE` statement and all of the `INSERT` statements for the data straight out of SSMS.

Comment: Be sure to read Noonand's comment below -- the check box is not under SCRIPT DATA = TRUE, instead it is under General section, choose the appropriate option for 'Types of data to script'.

Comment: If you only want to generate one insert statement do something like this; select * into newtable from existingtable where [your where clause], then just do as above on the new table

Comment: The Advanced button is in a really dumb spot. It's no wonder nobody ever finds this on their own. It seems like it goes with the "Save to file" option. Also, I wonder why it doesn't generate a more efficient insert statement instead of many multiple insert statements

Comment: This works the same way in newer versions as well. Confirmed it in SSMS 2014.

Comment: FYI if you select `Data only` and encounter `Cyclic dependencies found` error, switch to `Schema and data` to avoid the error. Happens in Management Studio v17.

Comment: Doesn't work for a view when you e.g. want to filter the data with a  where clause.

Comment: In theory creating a script for the entire DB should allow you to regenerate that DB, data and all. I do this with Postgres regularly. I tried this with SSMS 2014 and it failed when I ran the script. It did not matter whether the previous copy of the DB had been deleted first or not. It ended up inserting 100's of tables and SPs into master, which I then had to clean up. It may work fine with individual tables or with tables only, but I would recommend exercising this thoroughly before relying on it in any way.

Comment: In SSMS 17.3 you can change "Type of data to script" only if you select 1 table. For more than 1 table "Schema Only" is pre-selected and I couldn't change it.

Comment: Oh my gosh that saved us $200 in licensing fees strictly just for exporting insert statements Nice!!!

Comment: I'm getting just getting `USE [DB] GO`

Comment: This did not work for me with an always-encrypted column, even with SSMS correctly configured to query these columns, as also reported here (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37766452-generate-scripts-doesn-t-work-with-always-encrypte), whereas the Redgate Sql Prompt does work. And yes, this is only test data in this encrypted column, so don't judge me.

Comment: This appears to generate one statement per row.  Any idea on how to make it generate one statement for multiple rows, i.e. `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (...) VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...),(...),(...);` (maybe 100 rows per statement would be nice?)

Answer (score 113):

We use this stored procedure - it allows you to target specific tables, and use where clauses.  You can find the text [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt).

For example, it lets you do this:

```
EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles'
```

---

Source code copied from link:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

PRINT 'Using Master database'
USE master
GO

PRINT 'Checking for the existence of this procedure'
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('sp_generate_inserts','P')) IS NOT NULL --means, the procedure already exists
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Procedure already exists. So, dropping it'
        DROP PROC sp_generate_inserts
    END
GO

--Turn system object marking on
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 1
GO

CREATE PROC sp_generate_inserts
(
    @table_name varchar(776),       -- The table/view for which the INSERT statements will be generated using the existing data
    @target_table varchar(776) = NULL,  -- Use this parameter to specify a different table name into which the data will be inserted
    @include_column_list bit = 1,       -- Use this parameter to include/ommit column list in the generated INSERT statement
    @from varchar(800) = NULL,      -- Use this parameter to filter the rows based on a filter condition (using WHERE)
    @include_timestamp bit = 0,         -- Specify 1 for this parameter, if you want to include the TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION column's data in the INSERT statement
    @debug_mode bit = 0,            -- If @debug_mode is set to 1, the SQL statements constructed by this procedure will be printed for later examination
    @owner varchar(64) = NULL,      -- Use this parameter if you are not the owner of the table
    @ommit_images bit = 0,          -- Use this parameter to generate INSERT statements by omitting the 'image' columns
    @ommit_identity bit = 0,        -- Use this parameter to ommit the identity columns
    @top int = NULL,            -- Use this parameter to generate INSERT statements only for the TOP n rows
    @cols_to_include varchar(8000) = NULL,  -- List of columns to be included in the INSERT statement
    @cols_to_exclude varchar(8000) = NULL,  -- List of columns to be excluded from the INSERT statement
    @disable_constraints bit = 0,       -- When 1, disables foreign key constraints and enables them after the INSERT statements
    @ommit_computed_cols bit = 0        -- When 1, computed columns will not be included in the INSERT statement

)
AS
BEGIN

/***********************************************************************************************************
Procedure:  sp_generate_inserts  (Build 22) 
        (Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.)

Purpose:    To generate INSERT statements from existing data. 
        These INSERTS can be executed to regenerate the data at some other location.
        This procedure is also useful to create a database setup, where in you can 
        script your data along with your table definitions.

Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
            http://vyaskn.tripod.com
            http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt

Acknowledgements:
        Divya Kalra -- For beta testing
        Mark Charsley   -- For reporting a problem with scripting uniqueidentifier columns with NULL values
        Artur Zeygman   -- For helping me simplify a bit of code for handling non-dbo owned tables
        Joris Laperre   -- For reporting a regression bug in handling text/ntext columns

Tested on:  SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000

Date created:   January 17th 2001 21:52 GMT

Date modified:  May 1st 2002 19:50 GMT

Email:      vyaskn@hotmail.com

NOTE:       This procedure may not work with tables with too many columns.
        Results can be unpredictable with huge text columns or SQL Server 2000's sql_variant data types
        Whenever possible, Use @include_column_list parameter to ommit column list in the INSERT statement, for better results
        IMPORTANT: This procedure is not tested with internation data (Extended characters or Unicode). If needed
        you might want to convert the datatypes of character variables in this procedure to their respective unicode counterparts
        like nchar and nvarchar


Example 1:  To generate INSERT statements for table 'titles':

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles'

Example 2:  To ommit the column list in the INSERT statement: (Column list is included by default)
        IMPORTANT: If you have too many columns, you are advised to ommit column list, as shown below,
        to avoid erroneous results

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', @include_column_list = 0

Example 3:  To generate INSERT statements for 'titlesCopy' table from 'titles' table:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', 'titlesCopy'

Example 4:  To generate INSERT statements for 'titles' table for only those titles 
        which contain the word 'Computer' in them:
        NOTE: Do not complicate the FROM or WHERE clause here. It's assumed that you are good with T-SQL if you are using this parameter

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', @from = "from titles where title like '%Computer%'"

Example 5:  To specify that you want to include TIMESTAMP column's data as well in the INSERT statement:
        (By default TIMESTAMP column's data is not scripted)

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', @include_timestamp = 1

Example 6:  To print the debug information:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles', @debug_mode = 1

Example 7:  If you are not the owner of the table, use @owner parameter to specify the owner name
        To use this option, you must have SELECT permissions on that table

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts Nickstable, @owner = 'Nick'

Example 8:  To generate INSERT statements for the rest of the columns excluding images
        When using this otion, DO NOT set @include_column_list parameter to 0.

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts imgtable, @ommit_images = 1

Example 9:  To generate INSERT statements excluding (ommiting) IDENTITY columns:
        (By default IDENTITY columns are included in the INSERT statement)

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts mytable, @ommit_identity = 1

Example 10:     To generate INSERT statements for the TOP 10 rows in the table:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts mytable, @top = 10

Example 11:     To generate INSERT statements with only those columns you want:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts titles, @cols_to_include = "'title','title_id','au_id'"

Example 12:     To generate INSERT statements by omitting certain columns:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts titles, @cols_to_exclude = "'title','title_id','au_id'"

Example 13: To avoid checking the foreign key constraints while loading data with INSERT statements:

        EXEC sp_generate_inserts titles, @disable_constraints = 1

Example 14:     To exclude computed columns from the INSERT statement:
        EXEC sp_generate_inserts MyTable, @ommit_computed_cols = 1
***********************************************************************************************************/

SET NOCOUNT ON

--Making sure user only uses either @cols_to_include or @cols_to_exclude
IF ((@cols_to_include IS NOT NULL) AND (@cols_to_exclude IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Use either @cols_to_include or @cols_to_exclude. Do not use both the parameters at once',16,1)
        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: Both @cols_to_include and @cols_to_exclude parameters are specified
    END

--Making sure the @cols_to_include and @cols_to_exclude parameters are receiving values in proper format
IF ((@cols_to_include IS NOT NULL) AND (PATINDEX('''%''',@cols_to_include) = 0))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid use of @cols_to_include property',16,1)
        PRINT 'Specify column names surrounded by single quotes and separated by commas'
        PRINT 'Eg: EXEC sp_generate_inserts titles, @cols_to_include = "''title_id'',''title''"'
        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: Invalid use of @cols_to_include property
    END

IF ((@cols_to_exclude IS NOT NULL) AND (PATINDEX('''%''',@cols_to_exclude) = 0))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid use of @cols_to_exclude property',16,1)
        PRINT 'Specify column names surrounded by single quotes and separated by commas'
        PRINT 'Eg: EXEC sp_generate_inserts titles, @cols_to_exclude = "''title_id'',''title''"'
        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: Invalid use of @cols_to_exclude property
    END


--Checking to see if the database name is specified along wih the table name
--Your database context should be local to the table for which you want to generate INSERT statements
--specifying the database name is not allowed
IF (PARSENAME(@table_name,3)) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Do not specify the database name. Be in the required database and just specify the table name.',16,1)
        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: Database name is specified along with the table name, which is not allowed
    END

--Checking for the existence of 'user table' or 'view'
--This procedure is not written to work on system tables
--To script the data in system tables, just create a view on the system tables and script the view instead

IF @owner IS NULL
    BEGIN
        IF ((OBJECT_ID(@table_name,'U') IS NULL) AND (OBJECT_ID(@table_name,'V') IS NULL)) 
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('User table or view not found.',16,1)
                PRINT 'You may see this error, if you are not the owner of this table or view. In that case use @owner parameter to specify the owner name.'
                PRINT 'Make sure you have SELECT permission on that table or view.'
                RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: There is no user table or view with this name
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND (TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' OR TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @owner)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('User table or view not found.',16,1)
                PRINT 'You may see this error, if you are not the owner of this table. In that case use @owner parameter to specify the owner name.'
                PRINT 'Make sure you have SELECT permission on that table or view.'
                RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: There is no user table or view with this name      
            END
    END

--Variable declarations
DECLARE     @Column_ID int,         
        @Column_List varchar(8000), 
        @Column_Name varchar(128), 
        @Start_Insert varchar(786), 
        @Data_Type varchar(128), 
        @Actual_Values varchar(8000),   --This is the string that will be finally executed to generate INSERT statements
        @IDN varchar(128)       --Will contain the IDENTITY column's name in the table

--Variable Initialization
SET @IDN = ''
SET @Column_ID = 0
SET @Column_Name = ''
SET @Column_List = ''
SET @Actual_Values = ''

IF @owner IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @Start_Insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + '[' + RTRIM(COALESCE(@target_table,@table_name)) + ']' 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Start_Insert = 'INSERT ' + '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@owner)) + '].' + '[' + RTRIM(COALESCE(@target_table,@table_name)) + ']'      
    END


--To get the first column's ID

SELECT  @Column_ID = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION)  
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (NOLOCK) 
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND
(@owner IS NULL OR TABLE_SCHEMA = @owner)



--Loop through all the columns of the table, to get the column names and their data types
WHILE @Column_ID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Column_Name = QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), 
        @Data_Type = DATA_TYPE 
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE   ORDINAL_POSITION = @Column_ID AND 
        TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND
        (@owner IS NULL OR TABLE_SCHEMA = @owner)



        IF @cols_to_include IS NOT NULL --Selecting only user specified columns
        BEGIN
            IF CHARINDEX( '''' + SUBSTRING(@Column_Name,2,LEN(@Column_Name)-2) + '''',@cols_to_include) = 0 
            BEGIN
                GOTO SKIP_LOOP
            END
        END

        IF @cols_to_exclude IS NOT NULL --Selecting only user specified columns
        BEGIN
            IF CHARINDEX( '''' + SUBSTRING(@Column_Name,2,LEN(@Column_Name)-2) + '''',@cols_to_exclude) <> 0 
            BEGIN
                GOTO SKIP_LOOP
            END
        END

        --Making sure to output SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF in case the table has an IDENTITY column
        IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + @table_name),SUBSTRING(@Column_Name,2,LEN(@Column_Name) - 2),'IsIdentity')) = 1 
        BEGIN
            IF @ommit_identity = 0 --Determing whether to include or exclude the IDENTITY column
                SET @IDN = @Column_Name
            ELSE
                GOTO SKIP_LOOP          
        END

        --Making sure whether to output computed columns or not
        IF @ommit_computed_cols = 1
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + @table_name),SUBSTRING(@Column_Name,2,LEN(@Column_Name) - 2),'IsComputed')) = 1 
            BEGIN
                GOTO SKIP_LOOP                  
            END
        END

        --Tables with columns of IMAGE data type are not supported for obvious reasons
        IF(@Data_Type in ('image'))
            BEGIN
                IF (@ommit_images = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Tables with image columns are not supported.',16,1)
                        PRINT 'Use @ommit_images = 1 parameter to generate INSERTs for the rest of the columns.'
                        PRINT 'DO NOT ommit Column List in the INSERT statements. If you ommit column list using @include_column_list=0, the generated INSERTs will fail.'
                        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: There is a column with image data type
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    GOTO SKIP_LOOP
                    END
            END

        --Determining the data type of the column and depending on the data type, the VALUES part of
        --the INSERT statement is generated. Care is taken to handle columns with NULL values. Also
        --making sure, not to lose any data from flot, real, money, smallmomey, datetime columns
        SET @Actual_Values = @Actual_Values  +
        CASE 
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('char','varchar','nchar','nvarchar') 
                THEN 
                    'COALESCE('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(' + @Column_Name + '),'''''''','''''''''''')+'''''''',''NULL'')'
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('datetime','smalldatetime') 
                THEN 
                    'COALESCE('''''''' + RTRIM(CONVERT(char,' + @Column_Name + ',109))+'''''''',''NULL'')'
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('uniqueidentifier') 
                THEN  
                    'COALESCE('''''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(char(255),RTRIM(' + @Column_Name + ')),'''''''','''''''''''')+'''''''',''NULL'')'
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('text','ntext') 
                THEN  
                    'COALESCE('''''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8000),' + @Column_Name + '),'''''''','''''''''''')+'''''''',''NULL'')'                    
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('binary','varbinary') 
                THEN  
                    'COALESCE(RTRIM(CONVERT(char,' + 'CONVERT(int,' + @Column_Name + '))),''NULL'')'  
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('timestamp','rowversion') 
                THEN  
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @include_timestamp = 0 
                            THEN 
                                '''DEFAULT''' 
                            ELSE 
                                'COALESCE(RTRIM(CONVERT(char,' + 'CONVERT(int,' + @Column_Name + '))),''NULL'')'  
                    END
            WHEN @Data_Type IN ('float','real','money','smallmoney')
                THEN
                    'COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(' + 'CONVERT(char, ' +  @Column_Name  + ',2)' + ')),''NULL'')' 
            ELSE 
                'COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(' + 'CONVERT(char, ' +  @Column_Name  + ')' + ')),''NULL'')' 
        END   + '+' +  ''',''' + ' + '

        --Generating the column list for the INSERT statement
        SET @Column_List = @Column_List +  @Column_Name + ','   

        SKIP_LOOP: --The label used in GOTO

        SELECT  @Column_ID = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND 
        ORDINAL_POSITION > @Column_ID AND
        (@owner IS NULL OR TABLE_SCHEMA = @owner)


    --Loop ends here!
    END

--To get rid of the extra characters that got concatenated during the last run through the loop
SET @Column_List = LEFT(@Column_List,len(@Column_List) - 1)
SET @Actual_Values = LEFT(@Actual_Values,len(@Actual_Values) - 6)

IF LTRIM(@Column_List) = '' 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No columns to select. There should at least be one column to generate the output',16,1)
        RETURN -1 --Failure. Reason: Looks like all the columns are ommitted using the @cols_to_exclude parameter
    END

--Forming the final string that will be executed, to output the INSERT statements
IF (@include_column_list <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Actual_Values = 
            'SELECT ' +  
            CASE WHEN @top IS NULL OR @top < 0 THEN '' ELSE ' TOP ' + LTRIM(STR(@top)) + ' ' END + 
            '''' + RTRIM(@Start_Insert) + 
            ' ''+' + '''(' + RTRIM(@Column_List) +  '''+' + ''')''' + 
            ' +''VALUES(''+ ' +  @Actual_Values  + '+'')''' + ' ' + 
            COALESCE(@from,' FROM ' + CASE WHEN @owner IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@owner)) + '].' END + '[' + rtrim(@table_name) + ']' + '(NOLOCK)')
    END
ELSE IF (@include_column_list = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Actual_Values = 
            'SELECT ' + 
            CASE WHEN @top IS NULL OR @top < 0 THEN '' ELSE ' TOP ' + LTRIM(STR(@top)) + ' ' END + 
            '''' + RTRIM(@Start_Insert) + 
            ' '' +''VALUES(''+ ' +  @Actual_Values + '+'')''' + ' ' + 
            COALESCE(@from,' FROM ' + CASE WHEN @owner IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@owner)) + '].' END + '[' + rtrim(@table_name) + ']' + '(NOLOCK)')
    END 

--Determining whether to ouput any debug information
IF @debug_mode =1
    BEGIN
        PRINT '/*****START OF DEBUG INFORMATION*****'
        PRINT 'Beginning of the INSERT statement:'
        PRINT @Start_Insert
        PRINT ''
        PRINT 'The column list:'
        PRINT @Column_List
        PRINT ''
        PRINT 'The SELECT statement executed to generate the INSERTs'
        PRINT @Actual_Values
        PRINT ''
        PRINT '*****END OF DEBUG INFORMATION*****/'
        PRINT ''
    END

PRINT '--INSERTs generated by ''sp_generate_inserts'' stored procedure written by Vyas'
PRINT '--Build number: 22'
PRINT '--Problems/Suggestions? Contact Vyas @ vyaskn@hotmail.com'
PRINT '--http://vyaskn.tripod.com'
PRINT ''
PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT ON'
PRINT ''


--Determining whether to print IDENTITY_INSERT or not
IF (@IDN <> '')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' ON'
        PRINT 'GO'
        PRINT ''
    END


IF @disable_constraints = 1 AND (OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + @table_name, 'U') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF @owner IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@target_table, @table_name)) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' AS '--Code to disable constraints temporarily'
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@owner) + '.' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@target_table, @table_name)) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' AS '--Code to disable constraints temporarily'
            END

        PRINT 'GO'
    END

PRINT ''
PRINT 'PRINT ''Inserting values into ' + '[' + RTRIM(COALESCE(@target_table,@table_name)) + ']' + ''''


--All the hard work pays off here!!! You'll get your INSERT statements, when the next line executes!
EXEC (@Actual_Values)

PRINT 'PRINT ''Done'''
PRINT ''


IF @disable_constraints = 1 AND (OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + @table_name, 'U') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF @owner IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@target_table, @table_name)) + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'  AS '--Code to enable the previously disabled constraints'
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@owner) + '.' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@target_table, @table_name)) + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' AS '--Code to enable the previously disabled constraints'
            END

        PRINT 'GO'
    END

PRINT ''
IF (@IDN <> '')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(COALESCE(@owner,USER_NAME())) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' OFF'
        PRINT 'GO'
    END

PRINT 'SET NOCOUNT OFF'


SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN 0 --Success. We are done!
END

GO

PRINT 'Created the procedure'
GO


--Turn system object marking off
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 2
GO

PRINT 'Granting EXECUTE permission on sp_generate_inserts to all users'
GRANT EXEC ON sp_generate_inserts TO public

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO

PRINT 'Done'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, except that the generated INSERTs don't have a semicolon @ the end.  I added that and used it with success.  Thanks for answering the qstn!

Comment: must be something missing here, that sp doesn't seem to exist in my version of 2008

Comment: @jcollum - it's actually not a built-in stored procedure.  If you follow the link, you can get the text for the stored proc.

Comment: I'm Getting -  
Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_generate_inserts, Line 331
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.
Msg 536, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_generate_inserts, Line 332
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_generate_inserts, Line 336
No columns to select. There should at least be one column to generate the output
  Why?

Comment: @nimrod: I'm getting the same error. Using Sql Server 2008 and schemas.

Comment: @Gabriel: Sorry - i didn't get passed this - We are creating the inserts using a C# util.

Comment: I got this error too. To fix it, replace "EXEC master.dbo.sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 2" with "EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_generate_inserts" and remove the line "EXEC master.dbo.sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 1".

Comment: SEE THE ANSWER with the most upvotes, which should be the accepted answer here. This is built-in, you don't need a stored procedure...

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop, only that sometimes you need to be able to automate it through code, not have a user manualy perform the task through the GUI.

Comment: @DanielNolan could you explain your fix?

Comment: @DanielNolan your fix solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Note I was getting an error with that earlier version of the script, but there is a newer version (apparently for SQL 2005 and later) here:  http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts_2005.txt (that version did not error out for me, in SQL 2016)

Comment: Could someone grab the proc and paste it in the answer?  Firewalled here at work, and in the future that link may not work anyhow.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi: I have a copy in my snippet repo: https://github.com/cumminsjp/Agema/blob/master/scripts/db/mssql/generate_inserts.sql

Comment: Wanted to note that you should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix to user-defined stored procedures, since that's the namespace Microsoft is using for built in stored procedures and if they release a stored procedure with the same name, your code will break. Plus, if you use a different naming convention, you have an easy way of differentiating user and system stored procedures if you're going through metatables.

Comment: 12 years later and this still works on SQL Server 2019, AMAZING! Altered to run directly in the database I wanted since I didn't have rights to master. Created insert statements for me and with the WHERE clause set.

Comment: Been using this script for years and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 79):

This can be done using `Visual Studio` too (at least in version 2013 onwards).

In VS 2013 it is also possible **to filter** the list of rows the inserts statement are based on, this is something not possible in SSMS as for as I know.

Perform the following steps:

- Open the "SQL Server Object Explorer" window (menu: /View/SQL Server Object Explorer)
- Open / expand the database and its tables
- Right click on the table and choose "View data" from context menu
- This will display the data in the main area
- Optional step: Click on the filter icon "Sort and filter data set" (the fourth icon from the left on the row above the result) and apply some filter to one or more columns
- Click on the "Script" or "Script to File" icons (the icons on the right of the top row, they look like little sheets of paper)

This will create the (conditional) insert statements for the selected table to the active window or file.

**The "Filter" and "Script" buttons Visual Studio 2013**:

[image]

Comment: This is now my preferred way of pulling records out of one database to insert somewhere else - it just seems a lot simpler than going through the wizard in SSMS.

Comment: I couldn't get this to export binary fields :(

Comment: Your post is correct and easiest way using SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio , [here](https://dotnetvibes.com/2016/04/24/generating-sql-insert-scripts-in-just-2-clicks/)  is similar post which explains how **generate insert statement for first 1000 rows** hope helps.

Comment: Still there in SSDT using VS 2019 (16.8 preview 3). But still not in query results, only "View Data" on table or view.  You can filter, but you CANNOT reorder columns, for that have to create a view.  Strangely this works for views too.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I've been looking for something like this for a while.

Comment: I confirmed that this feature is available in Visual Studio 2022 (17.3.2)

Answer (score 61):

As mentioned by [@Mike Ritacco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316313/1501497) but updated for SSMS 2008 R2

1. Right click on the database name
2. Choose Tasks > Generate scripts
3. Depending on your settings the intro page may show or not
4. Choose 'Select specific database objects',
5. Expand the tree view and check the relevant tables
6. Click Next
7. Click Advanced
8. Under General section, choose the appropriate option for 'Types of data to script'
9. Complete the wizard

You will then get all of the INSERT statements for the data straight out of SSMS.

**EDIT 2016-10-25 SQL Server 2016/SSMS 13.0.15900.1**

1. Right click on the database name
2. Choose Tasks > Generate scripts
3. Depending on your settings the intro page may show or not
4. Choose 'Select specific database objects',
5. Expand the tree view and check the relevant tables
6. Click Next
7. Click Advanced
8. Under General section, choose the appropriate option for 'Types of data to
   script'
9. Click OK
10. Pick whether you want the output to go to a new query, the clipboard or a
    file
11. Click Next twice
12. Your script is prepared in accordance with the settings you picked above
13. Click Finish

Comment: hmm I don't know if we're using different versions of SSMS 2008 R2 but there's no 'advanced' option for me at all. what I had to do was select 'script data' in the 'choose script options' step. (BTW that option is not there in express edition)

Answer (score 29):

You can use SSMS Tools Pack (available for SQL Server 2005 and 2008). It comes with a feature for generating insert statements.

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: The only tool worked for very large nvarchar(max) content with tabs and new lines.

Comment: FYI this is a commercial product that currently costs 30 euro for a single dev. There's a 60 day trial license.

Answer (score 26):

I'm using SSMS 2008 version 10.0.5500.0.  In this version as part of the Generate Scripts wizard, instead of an Advanced button, there is the screen below.   In this case, I wanted just the data inserted and no create statements, so I had to change the two circled properties[image: Script Options]

Answer (score 16):

The [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982587/1501497) to sp_generate_inserts is pretty cool, here is a really simple version:

```
DECLARE @Fields VARCHAR(max); SET @Fields = '[QueueName], [iSort]' -- your fields, keep []
DECLARE @Table  VARCHAR(max); SET @Table  = 'Queues'               -- your table

DECLARE @SQL    VARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @S = ISNULL(@S + '' UNION '', ''INSERT INTO ' + @Table + '(' + @Fields + ')'') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
 ''SELECT '' + ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Fields, ',', ' + '', '' + '), '[', ''''''''' + CAST('),']',' AS VARCHAR(max)) + ''''''''') +' FROM ' + @Table + '
PRINT @S'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

On my system, I get this result:

```
INSERT INTO Queues([QueueName], [iSort])
SELECT 'WD: Auto Capture', '10' UNION 
SELECT 'Car/Lar', '11' UNION 
SELECT 'Scan Line', '21' UNION 
SELECT 'OCR', '22' UNION 
SELECT 'Dynamic Template', '23' UNION 
SELECT 'Fix MICR', '41' UNION 
SELECT 'Fix MICR (Supervisor)', '42' UNION 
SELECT 'Foreign MICR', '43' UNION 
...
```

Answer (score 16):

If you need a programmatic access, then you can use an open source stored procedure `GenerateInsert.

[INSERT statement(s) generator](http://github.com/drumsta/sql-generate-insert)

Just as a simple and quick example, to generate INSERT statements for a table `AdventureWorks.Person.AddressType` execute following statements:

```
USE [AdventureWorks];
GO
EXECUTE dbo.GenerateInsert @ObjectName = N'Person.AddressType';
```

This will generate the following script:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Person.AddressType ON
INSERT INTO Person.AddressType
([AddressTypeID],[Name],[rowguid],[ModifiedDate])
VALUES
 (1,N'Billing','B84F78B1-4EFE-4A0E-8CB7-70E9F112F886',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
,(2,N'Home','41BC2FF6-F0FC-475F-8EB9-CEC0805AA0F2',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
,(3,N'Main Office','8EEEC28C-07A2-4FB9-AD0A-42D4A0BBC575',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
,(4,N'Primary','24CB3088-4345-47C4-86C5-17B535133D1E',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
,(5,N'Shipping','B29DA3F8-19A3-47DA-9DAA-15C84F4A83A5',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
,(6,N'Archive','A67F238A-5BA2-444B-966C-0467ED9C427F',CONVERT(datetime,'2002-06-01 00:00:00.000',121))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Person.AddressType OFF
```

Comment: nice job! simple and does what it was meant to do. hope to use this for a loong time :)

Comment: after noticing a bug in the code, I made a pull request at github. thanks for sharing.

Comment: this actually works better than EXEC sp_generate_inserts 'titles'

Comment: @drumsta can you add an Include Column, Exclude Column List Parameter if needed, right now I only need few columns from my table? Thanks

Comment: Possible to use this to operate on multiple tables each with its own WHERE condition? For example, `from OrderHeader where OrderNumber=10000, from OrderDetail Where OrderHeaderId = 100` etc?

Answer (score 11):

My contribution to the problem, a Powershell INSERT script generator that lets you script multiple tables without having to use the cumbersome SSMS GUI.  Great for rapidly persisting "seed" data into source control.

1. Save the below script as "filename.ps1".
2. Make your own modifications to the areas under "CUSTOMIZE ME".
3. You can add the list of tables to script in any order.
4. You can open the script in Powershell ISE and hit the Play button, or simply execute the script in the Powershell command prompt.

By default, the INSERT script generated will be "SeedData.sql" under the same folder as the script.

You will need the SQL Server Management Objects assemblies installed, which should be there if you have SSMS installed.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
Add-Type -AssemblyName ("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")



#CUSTOMIZE ME
$outputFile = ".\SeedData.sql"
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True;"



$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($sqlConnection)
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conn)
$db = $srv.Databases[$srv.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName]
$scr = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter $srv
$scr.Options.FileName = $outputFile
$scr.Options.AppendToFile = $false
$scr.Options.ScriptSchema = $false
$scr.Options.ScriptData = $true
$scr.Options.NoCommandTerminator = $true

$tables = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UrnCollection



#CUSTOMIZE ME
$tables.Add($db.Tables["Category"].Urn)
$tables.Add($db.Tables["Product"].Urn)
$tables.Add($db.Tables["Vendor"].Urn)



[void]$scr.EnumScript($tables)

$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use inserts, use [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Comment: Valid in most cases but there can be good reasons for wanting to use inserts.

Comment: Indeed, @Steve Homer.  Grabbing a good DB initialization script, e.g. for EF Code First projects.  Yep, there are many times when I've needed this functionality.  BCP just didn't fit.

Answer (score 6):

[GenerateData](http://www.generatedata.com/) is an amazing tool for this. It's also very easy to make tweaks to it because the source code is available to you. A few nice features:

- Name generator for peoples names and places
- Ability to save Generation profile (after it is downloaded and set up locally)
- Ability to customize and manipulate the generation through scripts
- Many different outputs (CSV, Javascript, JSON, etc.) for the data (in case you need to test the set in different environments and want to skip the database access)
- **Free**. But consider donating if you find the software useful :).

[image: GUI]

Comment: I've never had any problems with it and I've used it numerous times. Perhaps you're not using the same version that the app is made for. In a worst case scenario you can create custom output by using their "Use custom HTML format". I think it's an excellent tool.

Comment: It does not map the types correctly, and also the sample data and insert statement create wrong quotations, I had to wade through to clean quite a bit of the script. But in the end realized dbschema was better IMHO

Comment: Interesting, I didn't find that and that wonder about how you were using it. Anyway, to each his own.

Comment: yeah it works for the very basic stuff, I let the site owner know last yr, but the output I'm referring to is the DB option to create the script for Sql Server. Its unfortunate since the script does go a long way... but on a 1000 table records insertion can be annoying.. still a nice tool for quick stuff

Comment: https://github.com/benkeen/generatedata

Comment: This tool does NOT read existing generated data to generate INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE.  It can only generate NEW data, unlike the other answers.  And I don't think the answer is clear which flavor of generate this tool does (file from data or new data).

Answer (score 6):

In order to get INSERT statement with filtered record(WHERE QUERY) you can

1. RIGHT CLICK TABLE SCRIPT TABLE AS > CREATE TO > NEW QUERY
2. RENAME IT WITH TEMP_TABLE
3. NOW RUN

   SELECT INTO TEMP_TABLE  FROM YOURFIRST TABLE WHERE NOW YOUR CRITERIA HERE

In this way you temp table will have only the record that you want ,
Now by running script wizard as explained by **@Mike Ritacco** with DATA ONLY you will get the exact insert statements.

Comment: Better and easier to use the SELECT INTO NEW_TABLE syntax without "CREATE":   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: will it create the table with keys ?

Comment: No, but it is not needed for INSERT STATEMENT (Topic question)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can try the SQL Server Publishing Wizard
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

It has a wizard that helps you script insert statements.

Comment: it is pre-installed:  “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4\SqlPubWiz.exe”

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate **INSERT** or **MERGE** statement with this simple and **free** application I wrote a few years ago:
[Data Script Writer](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/DataScriptWriter/) (Desktop Application for Windows)

[image]
Also, I wrote a blog post about these tools recently and approach to leveraging [SSDT](https://sqlplayer.net/category/ssdt/) for a deployment database with data. Find out more:
[Script and deploy the data for database from SSDT project](https://sqlplayer.net/2019/10/script-deploy-the-data-for-database-from-ssdt-project/)

Answer (score 5):

I made a simple to use utility, hope you enjoy.

- It doesn't need to create any objects on the database (easy to use on production environment).
- You don't need to install anything. It's just a regular script.
- You don't need special permissions. Just regular read access is enough.
- Let you copy all the lines of a table, or specify WHERE conditions so only the lines you want will be generated.
- Let you specify a single or multiple tables and different condition statements to be generated.

If the generated INSERT statements are being truncated, check the limit text length of the results on the Management Studio Options: `Tools > Options`, `Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid`, "Non XML data" value under "Maximum Characters Retrieved".

```
    -- Make sure you're on the correct database
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @Tables TABLE (
        TableName          varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Arguments           varchar(1000) NULL
    );

    -- INSERT HERE THE TABLES AND CONDITIONS YOU WANT TO GENERATE THE INSERT STATEMENTS
    INSERT INTO @Tables (TableName, Arguments) VALUES ('table1', 'WHERE field1 = 3101928464');
    -- (ADD MORE LINES IF YOU LIKE) INSERT INTO @Tables (TableName, Arguments) VALUES ('table2', 'WHERE field2 IN (1, 3, 5)');


    -- YOU DON'T NEED TO EDIT FROM NOW ON.
    -- Generating the Script
    DECLARE @TableName  varchar(50),
            @Arguments  varchar(1000),
            @ColumnName varchar(50),
            @strSQL     varchar(max),
            @strSQL2    varchar(max),
            @Lap        int,
            @Iden       int,
            @TypeOfData int;

    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TableName, Arguments FROM @Tables
    OPEN C1
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @TableName, @Arguments;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- If you want to delete the lines before inserting, uncomment the next line
        -- PRINT 'DELETE FROM ' + @TableName + ' ' + @Arguments

        SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' (';

        -- List all the columns from the table (to the INSERT into columns...)
        SET @Lap = 0;
        DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sc.name, sc.type FROM syscolumns sc INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON so.id = sc.id AND so.name = @TableName AND so.type = 'U' WHERE sc.colstat = 0 ORDER BY sc.colorder
        OPEN C2
        FETCH NEXT FROM C2 INTO @ColumnName, @TypeOfData;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF(@Lap>0)
            BEGIN
                SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ', ';
            END

            SET @strSQL = @strSQL + '[' + @ColumnName + ']';
            SET @Lap = @Lap + 1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM C2 INTO @ColumnName, @TypeOfData;
        END
        CLOSE C2
        DEALLOCATE C2

        SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ')'
        SET @strSQL2 = 'SELECT ''' + @strSQL + '
SELECT '' + ';

        -- List all the columns from the table again (for the SELECT that will be the input to the INSERT INTO statement)
        SET @Lap = 0;
        DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sc.name, sc.type FROM syscolumns sc INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON so.id = sc.id AND so.name = @TableName AND so.type = 'U' WHERE sc.colstat = 0 ORDER BY sc.colorder
        OPEN C2
        FETCH NEXT FROM C2 INTO @ColumnName, @TypeOfData;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF(@Lap>0)
            BEGIN
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + ' + '', '' + ';
            END

            -- For each data type, convert the data properly
            IF(@TypeOfData IN (55, 106, 56, 108, 63, 38, 109, 50, 48, 52)) -- Numbers
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + 'ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + '), ''NULL'') + '' as ' + @ColumnName + '''';
            ELSE IF(@TypeOfData IN (60, 62)) -- Float Numbers
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + 'ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(decimal(18,5), ' + @ColumnName + ')), ''NULL'') + '' as ' + @ColumnName + '''';
            ELSE IF(@TypeOfData IN (61, 111)) -- Datetime
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + 'ISNULL( '''''''' + CONVERT(varchar(max),' + @ColumnName + ', 121) + '''''''', ''NULL'') + '' as ' + @ColumnName + '''';
            ELSE IF(@TypeOfData IN (37, 47, 39, 0, 110)) -- Texts
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + 'ISNULL('''''''' + RTRIM(LTRIM(' + @ColumnName + ')) + '''''''', ''NULL'') + '' as ' + @ColumnName + '''';
            ELSE -- Unknown data types
                SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + 'ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + '), ''NULL'') + '' as ' + @ColumnName + '(INCORRECT TYPE ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @TypeOfData) + ')''';

            SET @Lap = @Lap + 1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM C2 INTO @ColumnName, @TypeOfData;
        END
        CLOSE C2
        DEALLOCATE C2

        SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + ' as [-- ' + @TableName + ']
FROM ' + @TableName + ' WITH (NOLOCK) ' + @Arguments

        SET @strSQL2 = @strSQL2 + ';
';
        --PRINT @strSQL;
        --PRINT @strSQL2;
        EXEC(@strSQL2);

        FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @TableName, @Arguments;
    END
    CLOSE C1
    DEALLOCATE C1

    ROLLBACK
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SELECT 0 AS Situacao;
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
        @strSQL As strSQL,
        @strSQL2 as strSQL2;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 4):

I use sqlite to do this. I find it very, very useful for creating scratch/test databases.

`sqlite3 foo.sqlite .dump   > foo_as_a_bunch_of_inserts.sql`

Answer (score 3):

There are many good scripts above for generating insert statements, but I attempted one of my own to make it as user friendly as possible and to also be able to do UPDATE statements. + package the result ready for .sql files that can be stored by date.

It takes as input your normal SELECT statement with WHERE clause, then outputs a list of Insert statements and update statements. Together they form a sort of IF NOT EXISTS () INSERT ELSE UPDATE It is handy too when there are non-updatable columns that need exclusion from the final INSERT/UPDATE statement.

Another thing that below script can do is: it can even handle INNER JOINs with other tables as input statement for the stored proc. It can be handy as a poor man's Release management tool that sits right at your finger tips where you are typing the sql SELECT statements all day.

original post : [Generate UPDATE statement in SQL Server for specific table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603752/generate-update-statement-in-sql-server-for-specific-table#new-answer)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_generate_updates] (
    @fullquery              nvarchar(max) = '',
    @ignore_field_input     nvarchar(MAX) = '',
    @PK_COLUMN_NAME         nvarchar(MAX) = ''
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
/*
-- For Standard USAGE: (where clause is mandatory)
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] 'select * from dbo.mytable where mytext=''1''  ' 
        OR
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] "select * from dbo.mytable where mytext='1'    "

-- For ignoring specific columns  (to ignore in the UPDATE and INSERT SQL statement) 
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] 'select * from dbo.mytable where 1=1  ' , 'Column01,Column02'

-- For just updates without insert statement (replace the * )
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] 'select Column01, Column02 from dbo.mytable where 1=1  ' 

-- For tables without a primary key: construct the key in the third variable
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] 'select * from dbo.mytable where 1=1  '  ,'','your_chosen_primary_key_Col1,key_Col2'

-- For complex updates with JOINED tables 
                EXEC [sp_generate_updates] 'select o1.Name,  o1.category, o2.name+ '_hello_world' as #name 
                                            from overnightsetting o1 
                                            inner join overnightsetting o2  on o1.name=o2.name  
                                            where o1.name like '%appserver%' 
                (REMARK about above:   the use of # in front of a column name (so #abc) can do an update of that columname (abc) with any column from an inner joined table where you use the alias #abc )


-------------README for the deeper interested person:
            Goal of the Stored PROCEDURE is to get updates from simple SQL SELECT statements. It is made ot be simple but fast and powerfull. As always => power is nothing without control, so check before you execute.
            Its power sits also in the fact that you can make insert statements, so combined gives you a  "IF NOT EXISTS()  INSERT "   capability. 

            The scripts work were there are primary keys or identity columns on table you want to update (/ or make inserts for).
            It will also works when no primary keys / identity column exist(s) and you define them yourselve. But then be carefull (duplicate hits can occur). When the table has a primary key it will always be used.
            The script works with a real  temporary table, made on the fly   (APPROPRIATE RIGHTS needed), to put the values inside from the script, then add 3 columns for constructing the "insert into tableX (...) values ()" ,  and the 2 update statement.
            We work with temporary structures like   "where columnname = {Columnname}" and then later do the update on that temptable for the columns values found on that same line.
                    example  "where columnname = {Columnname}"  for birthdate becomes   "where birthdate = {birthdate}" an then we find the birthdate value on that line inside the temp table.
            So then the statement becomes  "where birthdate = {19800417}"
            Enjoy releasing scripts as of now...                                        by  Pieter van Nederkassel  - freeware "CC BY-SA" (+use at own risk)
*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ignore','U') IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #ignore
DECLARE @stringsplit_table               TABLE (col nvarchar(255), dtype  nvarchar(255)) -- table to store the primary keys or identity key
DECLARE @PK_condition                    nvarchar(512), -- placeholder for WHERE pk_field1 = pk_value1 AND pk_field2 = pk_value2 AND ...
        @pkstring                        NVARCHAR(512),  -- sting to store the primary keys or the idendity key
        @table_name                      nvarchar(512), -- (left) table name, including schema
        @table_N_where_clause            nvarchar(max), -- tablename 
        @table_alias                     nvarchar(512), -- holds the (left) table alias if one available, else @table_name
        @table_schema                    NVARCHAR(30),  -- schema of @table_name
        @update_list1                    NVARCHAR(MAX), -- placeholder for SET fields section of update
        @update_list2                    NVARCHAR(MAX), -- placeholder for SET fields section of update value comming from other tables in the join, other than the main table to update => updateof base table possible with inner join
        @list_all_cols                   BIT = 0,       -- placeholder for values for the insert into table VALUES command
        @select_list                     NVARCHAR(MAX), -- placeholder for SELECT fields of (left) table
        @COLUMN_NAME                     NVARCHAR(255), -- will hold column names of the (left) table
        @sql                             NVARCHAR(MAX), -- sql statement variable
        @getdate                         NVARCHAR(17),  -- transform getdate() to YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMMM
        @tmp_table                       NVARCHAR(255), -- will hold the name of a physical temp table
        @pk_separator                    NVARCHAR(1),   -- separator used in @PK_COLUMN_NAME if provided (only checking obvious ones ,;|-)
        @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE           NVARCHAR(100), -- needed for insert statements to convert to right text string
        @own_pk                          BIT = 0        -- check if table has PK (0) or if provided PK will be used (1)




set @ignore_field_input=replace(replace(replace(@ignore_field_input,' ',''),'[',''),']','')
set @PK_COLUMN_NAME=    replace(replace(replace(@PK_COLUMN_NAME,    ' ',''),'[',''),']','')

-- first we remove all linefeeds from the user query
set @fullquery=replace(replace(replace(@fullquery,char(10),''),char(13),' '),'  ',' ')
set @table_N_where_clause=@fullquery
if charindex ('order by' , @table_N_where_clause) > 0
    print ' WARNING:        ORDER BY NOT ALLOWED IN UPDATE ...'
if @PK_COLUMN_NAME <> ''
    select ' WARNING:        IF you select your own primary keys, make double sure before doing the update statements below!! '
--print @table_N_where_clause
if charindex ('select ' , @table_N_where_clause) = 0
    set @table_N_where_clause= 'select * from ' + @table_N_where_clause
if charindex ('select ' , @table_N_where_clause) > 0
    exec (@table_N_where_clause)

set @table_N_where_clause=rtrim(ltrim(substring(@table_N_where_clause,CHARINDEX(' from ', @table_N_where_clause )+6, 4000)))
--print @table_N_where_clause 
set @table_name=left(@table_N_where_clause,CHARINDEX(' ', @table_N_where_clause )-1)


IF CHARINDEX('where ', @table_N_where_clause) > 0             SELECT @table_alias = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@table_N_where_clause,1, CHARINDEX('where ', @table_N_where_clause )-1),'(nolock)',''),@table_name,'')))
IF CHARINDEX('join ',  @table_alias) > 0                      SELECT @table_alias = SUBSTRING(@table_alias, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @table_alias)-1) -- until next space
IF LEN(@table_alias) = 0                                      SELECT @table_alias = @table_name
IF (charindex (' *' , @fullquery) > 0 or charindex (@table_alias+'.*' , @fullquery) > 0 )     set @list_all_cols=1
/*       
       print @fullquery     
       print @table_alias
       print @table_N_where_clause
       print @table_name
*/


-- Prepare PK condition
        SELECT @table_schema = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@table_name) > 0 THEN LEFT(@table_name, CHARINDEX('.',@table_name)-1) ELSE 'dbo' END

        SELECT @PK_condition = ISNULL(@PK_condition + ' AND ', '') + QUOTENAME('pk_'+COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME('pk_'+COLUMN_NAME,'{')
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
        AND TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

        SELECT @pkstring = ISNULL(@pkstring + ', ', '') + @table_alias + '.' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS pk_' + COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i1
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(i1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
        AND i1.TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
        AND i1.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

            -- if no primary keys exist then we try for identity columns
                IF @PK_condition is null SELECT @PK_condition = ISNULL(@PK_condition + ' AND ', '') + QUOTENAME('pk_'+COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME('pk_'+COLUMN_NAME,'{')
                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
                AND TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

                IF @pkstring is null SELECT @pkstring = ISNULL(@pkstring + ', ', '') + @table_alias + '.' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS pk_' + COLUMN_NAME
                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
                AND TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
-- Same but in form of a table

        INSERT INTO @stringsplit_table
        SELECT 'pk_'+i1.COLUMN_NAME as col, i2.DATA_TYPE as dtype
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i1
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i2
        on  i1.TABLE_NAME = i2.TABLE_NAME AND i1.TABLE_SCHEMA =  i2.TABLE_SCHEMA
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(i1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
        AND i1.TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
        AND i1.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

                -- if no primary keys exist then we try for identity columns
                IF 0=(select count(*) from @stringsplit_table) INSERT INTO @stringsplit_table
                SELECT 'pk_'+i2.COLUMN_NAME as col, i2.DATA_TYPE as dtype
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i2
                WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(i2.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+i2.TABLE_NAME), i2.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
                AND i2.TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
                AND i2.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

-- NOW handling the primary key given as parameter to the main batch

SELECT @pk_separator = ',' -- take this as default, we'll check lower if it's a different one
IF (@PK_condition IS NULL OR @PK_condition = '') AND @PK_COLUMN_NAME <> ''
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(';', @PK_COLUMN_NAME) > 0
        SELECT @pk_separator = ';'
    ELSE IF CHARINDEX('|', @PK_COLUMN_NAME) > 0
        SELECT @pk_separator = '|'
    ELSE IF CHARINDEX('-', @PK_COLUMN_NAME) > 0
        SELECT @pk_separator = '-'

    SELECT @PK_condition = NULL -- make sure to make it NULL, in case it was ''
    INSERT INTO @stringsplit_table
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value)) , 'datetime'  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PK_COLUMN_NAME, @pk_separator) x  
    SELECT @PK_condition = ISNULL(@PK_condition + ' AND ', '') + QUOTENAME(x.col) + ' = ' + replace(QUOTENAME(x.col,'{'),'{','{pk_')
      FROM @stringsplit_table x

    SELECT @PK_COLUMN_NAME = NULL -- make sure to make it NULL, in case it was ''
    SELECT @PK_COLUMN_NAME = ISNULL(@PK_COLUMN_NAME + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(x.col) + ' as pk_' + x.col
      FROM @stringsplit_table x
    --print 'pkcolumns  '+ isnull(@PK_COLUMN_NAME,'')
    update @stringsplit_table set col='pk_' + col
    SELECT @own_pk = 1
END
ELSE IF (@PK_condition IS NULL OR @PK_condition = '') AND @PK_COLUMN_NAME = ''
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No Primary key or Identity column available on table. Add some columns as the third parameter when calling this SP to make your own temporary PK., also remove  [] from tablename',17,1)
END


-- IF there are no primary keys or an identity key in the table active, then use the given columns as a primary key


if isnull(@pkstring,'')   = ''  set    @pkstring  = @PK_COLUMN_NAME
IF ISNULL(@pkstring, '') <> ''  SELECT @fullquery = REPLACE(@fullquery, 'SELECT ','SELECT ' + @pkstring + ',' )
--print @pkstring




-- ignore fields for UPDATE STATEMENT (not ignored for the insert statement,  in iserts statement we ignore only identity Columns and the columns provided with the main stored proc )
-- Place here all fields that you know can not be converted to nvarchar() values correctly, an thus should not be scripted for updates)
-- for insert we will take these fields along, although they will be incorrectly represented!!!!!!!!!!!!!.
SELECT           ignore_field = 'uniqueidXXXX' INTO #ignore 
UNION ALL SELECT ignore_field = 'UPDATEMASKXXXX'
UNION ALL SELECT ignore_field = 'UIDXXXXX'
UNION ALL SELECT value FROM  string_split(@ignore_field_input,@pk_separator)




SELECT @getdate = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121), '-', ''), ' ', ''), ':', ''), '.', '')
SELECT @tmp_table = 'Release_DATA__' + @getdate + '__' + REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 

SET @sql = replace( @fullquery,  ' from ',  ' INTO ' + @tmp_table +' from ')
----print (@sql)
exec (@sql)



SELECT @sql = N'alter table ' + @tmp_table + N'  add update_stmt1  nvarchar(max), update_stmt2 nvarchar(max) , update_stmt3 nvarchar(max)'
EXEC (@sql)

-- Prepare update field list (only columns from the temp table are taken if they also exist in the base table to update)
SELECT @update_list1 = ISNULL(@update_list1 + ', ', '') + 
                      CASE WHEN C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'ModifiedBy' THEN '[ModifiedBy] = left(right(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),[Modified],121),''''-'''',''''''''),19) +''''-''''+right(SUSER_NAME(),30),50)'
                           WHEN C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'Modified' THEN '[Modified] = GETDATE()'
                           ELSE QUOTENAME(C1.COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(C1.COLUMN_NAME,'{')
                      END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
on c1.COLUMN_NAME =c2.COLUMN_NAME and c2.TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','')  AND c2.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
WHERE c1.TABLE_NAME = @tmp_table --REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
AND QUOTENAME(c1.COLUMN_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT QUOTENAME(ignore_field) FROM #ignore) -- eliminate binary, image etc value here
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(c2.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+c2.TABLE_NAME), c2.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') <> 1
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ku 
                 WHERE 1 = 1
                   AND ku.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME
                   AND ku.TABLE_SCHEMA = c2.TABLE_SCHEMA
                   AND ku.COLUMN_NAME = c2.COLUMN_NAME
                   AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(ku.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @stringsplit_table x WHERE x.col = c2.COLUMN_NAME AND @own_pk = 1)

-- Prepare update field list  (here we only take columns that commence with a #, as this is our queue for doing the update that comes from an inner joined table)
SELECT @update_list2 = ISNULL(@update_list2 + ', ', '') +  QUOTENAME(replace( C1.COLUMN_NAME,'#','')) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(C1.COLUMN_NAME,'{')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
WHERE c1.TABLE_NAME = @tmp_table --AND c1.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
AND QUOTENAME(c1.COLUMN_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT QUOTENAME(ignore_field) FROM #ignore) -- eliminate binary, image etc value here
AND c1.COLUMN_NAME like '#%'

-- similar for select list, but take all fields
SELECT @select_list = ISNULL(@select_list + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') <> 1  -- Identity columns are filled automatically by MSSQL, not needed at Insert statement
AND QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT QUOTENAME(ignore_field) FROM #ignore) -- eliminate binary, image etc value here


SELECT @PK_condition = REPLACE(@PK_condition, '[pk_', '[')
set @select_list='if not exists (select * from '+  REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') +'  where '+  @PK_condition +')  INSERT INTO '+ REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','')   + '('+ @select_list  + ') VALUES (' + replace(replace(@select_list,'[','{'),']','}') + ')'
SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + ' set update_stmt1 = ''' + @select_list + '''' 
if @list_all_cols=1 EXEC (@sql)



--print 'select==========  ' + @select_list
--print 'update==========  ' + @update_list1


SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N'
set update_stmt2 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),''UPDATE ' + @table_name + 
                                          N' SET ' + @update_list1 + N''' + ''' +
                                          N' WHERE ' + @PK_condition + N''') ' 

EXEC (@sql)
--print @sql



SELECT @sql = N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N'
set update_stmt3 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),''UPDATE ' + @table_name + 
                                          N' SET ' + @update_list2 + N''' + ''' +
                                          N' WHERE ' + @PK_condition + N''') ' 

EXEC (@sql)
--print @sql


-- LOOPING OVER ALL base tables column for the INSERT INTO .... VALUES
DECLARE c_columns CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = (CASE WHEN @list_all_cols=0 THEN @tmp_table ELSE REPLACE(@table_name,@table_schema+'.','') END )
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
        UNION--pned
    SELECT col, 'datetime' FROM @stringsplit_table

OPEN c_columns
FETCH NEXT FROM c_columns INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 
    CASE WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('char','varchar','nchar','nvarchar')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('float','real','money','smallmoney')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],126)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) '
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('uniqueidentifier')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('text','ntext')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('xxxx','yyyy')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('binary','varbinary')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('XML','xml')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],0)),     '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('datetime','smalldatetime')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],121)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) '
    ELSE  
                  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt1 = REPLACE(update_stmt1, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) '
    END
    ----PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_columns INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE
END
CLOSE c_columns
DEALLOCATE c_columns

--SELECT col FROM @stringsplit_table -- these are the primary keys

-- LOOPING OVER ALL temp tables column for the Update values
DECLARE c_columns CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME =  @tmp_table --    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
       UNION--pned
    SELECT col, 'datetime' FROM @stringsplit_table

OPEN c_columns
FETCH NEXT FROM c_columns INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 
    CASE WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('char','varchar','nchar','nvarchar')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('float','real','money','smallmoney')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],126)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],126)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')) '
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('uniqueidentifier')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('text','ntext')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('xxxx','yyyy')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('binary','varbinary')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('XML','xml')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],0)),     '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],0)),     '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
        WHEN @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE IN ('datetime','smalldatetime')
            THEN  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],121)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'],121)),   '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
    ELSE    
                  N'UPDATE ' + @tmp_table + N' SET update_stmt2 = REPLACE(update_stmt2, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL'')), update_stmt3 = REPLACE(update_stmt3, ''{' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'}'', ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[' + @COLUMN_NAME + N'])),       '''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''', ''NULL''))  ' 
    END
    EXEC (@sql)
    ----print @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_columns INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME_DATA_TYPE
END
CLOSE c_columns
DEALLOCATE c_columns

SET @sql = 'Select * from  ' + @tmp_table + ';'
--exec (@sql)

SELECT @sql = N'
IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @tmp_table + N''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
       SELECT   ''USE ' + DB_NAME()  + '''  as executelist 
              UNION ALL
       SELECT   ''GO ''  as executelist 
              UNION ALL
       SELECT   '' /*PRESCRIPT CHECK  */              ' + replace(@fullquery,'''','''''')+''' as executelist 
              UNION ALL
       SELECT update_stmt1 as executelist FROM ' + @tmp_table + N' where update_stmt1 is not null
              UNION ALL
       SELECT update_stmt2 as executelist FROM ' + @tmp_table + N' where update_stmt2 is not null
              UNION ALL
       SELECT isnull(update_stmt3, '' add more columns inn query please'')  as executelist FROM ' + @tmp_table + N' where update_stmt3 is not null
              UNION ALL
       SELECT ''--EXEC usp_AddInstalledScript 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, ''''' + @tmp_table + '.sql'''', 2 ''  as executelist
              UNION ALL 
       SELECT   '' /*VERIFY WITH:  */              ' + replace(@fullquery,'''','''''')+''' as executelist 
              UNION ALL
       SELECT ''-- SCRIPT LOCATION:      F:\CopyPaste\++Distributionpoint++\Release_Management\' + @tmp_table + '.sql''  as executelist   
END'
exec (@sql)

SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @tmp_table + ';'
exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just backup the data before your work with it, then restore when you want it to be refreshed?

if you must generate inserts try: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts

Comment: I'd like the flexibility to edit the data in the INSERTs if I want to.  Other than that, no real reason...  I need to research the syntax of RESTORE and BACKUP so I can do that from a script.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather use Google Sheets, use [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io/?ref=so_sync) to Send the table to a Sheet, then insert rows on a schedule, as they're added to the Sheet.

See [here](https://intercom.help/seekwell/seekwell-desktop/sync-sheets-with-your-database-desktop-app) for the step by step process , or watch a [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyBKB1z37mk&t=4s) of the feature here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have data in a production database yet?  If so, you could setup a period refresh of the data via DTS.  We do ours weekly on the weekends and it is very nice to have clean, real data every week for our testing.

If you don't have production yet, then you should create a database that is they want you want it (fresh).  Then, duplicate that database and use that newly created database as your test environment.  When you want the clean version, simply duplicate your clean one again and [Bob's your uncle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob's_your_uncle).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understand your question correctly.

If you have data in MS-Access, which you want to move it to SQL Server - you could use DTS.
And, I guess you could use SQL profiler to see all the INSERT statements going by, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I have also researched lot on this, but I could not get the concrete solution for this. Currently the approach I follow is copy the contents in excel from SQL Server Managment studio and then import the data into Oracle-TOAD and then generate the insert statements

Comment: Hi Vineet, if you would try my solution and let me know what doesn't suit your needs I would happy to help you with automated SQL script generation. http://github.com/drumsta/sql-generate-insert

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as difficult or as simple as you want. I prefer the latter.

If you already have a dataset, all you have to do is add an action query in MS Access:

insert into Table1("column list here") select "column list here" from Table2

NOTE: Table2 could be a query and Table1 and Table2 could be an MS Access table or Sql Server table

Comment: MS Access is a pretty handy database pocketknife, but I was looking for solutions that were native to SQL Server.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Data Studio - Simple Data Scripter](https://github.com/ecirpnaes/SimpleDataScripter) extension.

After `INSERT ...` it generates `UNION ALL SELECT` per row.

Azure Data Studio UI is based on VSCode, and I find it to be intuitive and fast, including this OSS extension.

Comment: I use **ADS/Azure Data Studio** for exports since it supports .xlsx out of the box, and I have to send those files to my business users a couple times per week.

Comment: And for larger tables sometimes I make a local copy of data (single table backup).  Xlsx are space efficient since they're compressed by default.

Comment: But sp_generate_inserts looks great, going to give that a go next time.