# SSMS: Create a table script from results of a procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a piece of dynamic sql query. I'd like to keep the result in a temp table. But the query returns +100 fields so I'd prefer not to type the `Create table` script manually.

Is it possible in Sql Server Management Studio to script out the results returned by the procedure into a create table script.

So let's say that in a new query panel I execute my script. Below I get the returned results. Option I'm looking for is something like e.g. right clicking the results and selecting "Script into a table". Or something similar to what you get when you select "Edit top 200 rows" on a table and then in the returned results when you right click -> Pane -> SQL you can edit the SQL that generated the results.

Is anything like that possible in SSMS for results of a procedure? If external tools are required are there any that are free? I'm using SQL Server 2012 and SSMS 2012. Some tools that where available for previous versions are licensed for 2012.

Below some mocked version of the core code in the procedure:

```
exec dbo.spDynamic
    @ID , 
    @ID2 ,
    @Parameters ,
    @prefixLogic,
    @selectprefix,
    @selectsuffix,
    @Table_1,
    @Function_1,
    @SelectExtra_1,
    @Where_1,
    @Function_2,
    @SelectExtra_2,
    @Where_2,
    @On,
    @finalWhere
    @tempSchema
    @tempTable
    @tempWhere
```

And here's the essential part of the spDynamic:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql =
    + @parameterLogic 
    + ' ' + @prefixlogic
    + @selectprefix
    + ' SELECT ' + @DeltaLogic
    + ' FROM ( Select * ' + Case When @ID < 0 Then Replace(@SelectExtra_1, '<ID>', CAST(@ID AS nvarchar))
                                When @ID = 0 Then Replace(@SelectExtra_2, '<ID>', CAST(@ID AS nvarchar))
                                Else Replace(@Table_1, '<ID>', CAST(@ID AS nvarchar)) End

        + ' From ' + Case When @ID < 0 Then @Function_1 + ' ' + @Where_1 
                        When @ID = 0 Then @Function_2 + ' ' + @Where_2 
                        Else @tempSchema + @tempTable 
        + ' ' + Replace(@tempWhere, '<ID>', CAST(@ID AS nvarchar)) End
    + ' ) A '  
    + ' FULL OUTER JOIN '
    + ' ( Select * ' + Case When @ID2 < 0 Then Replace(@SelectExtra_1, '<ID>', CAST(@ID2 AS nvarchar))
                                When @ID2 = 0 Then Replace(@SelectExtra_2, '<ID>', CAST(@ID2 AS nvarchar))
                                Else Replace(@Table_1, '<ID>', CAST(@ID2 AS nvarchar)) End
        + ' From ' + Case When @ID2 < 0 Then @Function_1 + ' ' + @Where_1 
                When @ID2 = 0 Then @Function_2 + ' ' + @Where_2 
                Else @tempSchema + @tempTable 
        + ' ' + Replace(@tempWhere, '<ID>', CAST(@ID2 AS nvarchar)) End
    + ' ) B ' + @on
    + @finalWhere
    + @selectsuffix

exec sp_sqlexec @sql
```

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805275/create-an-insert-script-from-select-results

Comment: Yes, I had been checking that one before I asked my question. Unfortunately I have to rely on free tools if possible. I'll add that to the question. As to other suggestions I'd prefer avoiding typing the table columns manually.

Comment: Perhaps you can alter your dynamic sql query to do the insert into the temp table?

Comment: @jpw Is it possible without manually declaring the temp table? I wont to avoid typing in all +100 columns.

Comment: @jpw I've added a mocked version of the procedure in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to execute the stored procedure inside an `OPENROWSET` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table).

This allows you to create the table on-the-fly, for example by writing:

```
SELECT * INTO MyTempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes',
    'EXEC myStoredProc')
```

If you don't want actual data into `MyTempTable`, you could add `WHERE 1 = 0` at the end. Afterwards, you can then script out MyTempTable just like any other table.

Comment: I keep getting some errors. I guess there are some errors in the connections string. I'm also getting “Deferred prepare could not be completed". Still `OPENROWSET` sounds like right way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) tool bar then it has a "script grid data" option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will create a table called `NewTable`

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM AnotherTable
```

Can you could alter your dynamic SQL to do this?