# Generate insert script for selected records?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following data:

```
Pk_Id  ProductName           Fk_CompanyId       Price
------------------------------------------------------
1      AMX                   1                  10.00
2      ABC                   1                  11.00
3      APEX                  1                  12.00
4      AMX                   1                  10.00
5      ABC                   1                  11.00
6      APEX                  1                  12.00
7      AMX                   2                  10.00
8      ABC                   2                  11.00
9      APEX                  2                  12.00
```

I want to generate Insert script for migrating records whose Fk_CompanyId is 1.

There is an insert script option to generate script for all records but I want to filter some records to migrate to another database.

Comment: The famous Vyas script
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt

Comment: Conditional insert statements can also be create using Visual Studio 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36426678/4424024

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are using the SQL Management Studio, you can right click your DB name and select 
Tasks > Import/Export data and follow the wizard.
one of the steps is called "Specify Table Copy or Query" where there is an option to write a query to specify the data to transfer, so you can simply specify the following query:

```
select * from [Table] where Fk_CompanyId = 1
```

Comment: my destnation table has PkID as Identity but i made  set identity on and it worked

Comment: @Tamir How perform this operation using SMO library?

Comment: @Jalal, take a look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer.aspx
you will find a property named "scripter". I think that will do the work

Comment: If migrating to new database,In Visual Studio 2013 there is Data Comparison tool which will help you to **Auto Generate Script** from source database to Run in Target Database check [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS108) video or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/685073/2218697) post, hope helps someone.

Comment: But this answer's solution does not generate an "insert" script as the original question requested. It only allows you to use a query to get a dataset and then export the dataset to a destination, which is not an insert script. I am using SSMS 2012.

Comment: @jyao Correct, this does not give an insert query. What I did was I exported the data to a new temporary table that I made and then generated a Data script from there using the `Generate Scripts` option on the Database. That exported only the needed records. It's quite a hassle but I haven't found another option to directly export records to a new query.

Comment: Is there a way to have INSERT queries as results?

Comment: This answer does not address the need "I want to generate Insert script" and therefore does not help the community.  How do we take points away from the OP for accepting this answer?

Answer (score 51):

If possible use Visual Studio. The Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) bring a built in functionality for this since the March 2014 release:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open "View" → "SQL Server Object Explorer"
3. Add a connection to your Server
4. Expand the relevant database
5. Expand the "Tables" folder
6. Right click on relevant table
7. Select "View Data" from context menu
8. In the new window, viewing the data use the "Sort and filter
   dataset" functionality in the tool bar to apply your filter. Note that this functionality is limited and you can't write explicit SQL queries.
9. After you have applied your filter and see only the data you want, click on "Script" or "Script to file" in the tool bar
10. Voilà - Here you have your insert script for your filtered data

Note: Be careful, the "View Data" window is just like SSMS "Edit Top 200 Rows"- you can edit data right away

*(Tested with Visual Studio 2015 with Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) Version 14.0.60812.0 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012)*

Comment: Nice suggestion. One drawback noticed: binary data is exported as `<Binary Data>`.

Comment: You can write a query from Visual Studio and perform a right click -> export data from the limited result set, rather than doing so from the UI and its limited features.

From step 4 above, right click on your database and select "New Query". 

Write your query with conditions in the where clause, and execute it.

In the results, right click and you'll be presented with a "Script as Inserts" option.

You'll need to do a minor amount of massaging since it generates the insert into a global temp table.

Answer (score 37):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_generate_insertscripts
(
    @TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    @FILTER_CONDITION VARCHAR(MAX)=''   -- where TableId = 5 or some value
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
        @CSV_COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX),
        @QUOTED_DATA VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX),
        @FILTER VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @TABLE_NAME=@TABLENAME

SELECT @FILTER=@FILTER_CONDITION

SELECT @CSV_COLUMN=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ',['+ NAME +']' FROM sys.all_columns 
     WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME) AND 
     is_identity!=1 FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' ISNULL(QUOTENAME('+NAME+','+QUOTENAME('''','''''')+'),'+'''NULL'''+')+'','''+'+' FROM sys.all_columns 
     WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME) AND 
     is_identity!=1 FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @TEXT='SELECT ''INSERT INTO '+@TABLE_NAME+'('+@CSV_COLUMN+')VALUES('''+'+'+SUBSTRING(@QUOTED_DATA,1,LEN(@QUOTED_DATA)-5)+'+'+''')'''+' Insert_Scripts FROM '+@TABLE_NAME + @FILTER

--SELECT @CSV_COLUMN AS CSV_COLUMN,@QUOTED_DATA AS QUOTED_DATA,@TEXT TEXT

EXECUTE (@TEXT)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```

Comment: Please provide your answer, with proper explanation and proper alignment. Just posting your code is not enough.

Comment: @Karthikeyan I will provide the step by step explantion of my sp after few days when i got time.

Comment: @Karthikeyan  see my edited post through this link for explanation of above query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526461/converting-select-results-into-insert-script

Comment: This is awesome. I noticed that you need to add a space in the TABLENAME param so that it does not error out by concatenating with the FILTER_CONDITION

Comment: I have 'Key' column name in the table and it failed to create an insert script. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.

Comment: you need to wrap key column from select list into square bracket because key is SQL keyword that's it showing error if not solve after trying this please provide screenshot

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.  It is flexible for any table.  I made a few small changes.  At the end of the longest line, change `+ @FILTER` to `+ IIF(@FILTER='','',' WHERE ' + @FILTER)` so that you can pass a filter without including the word `WHERE`.  Another change was to add `AND system_type_id <> 189 AND is_computed=0` within the WHERE of the two SELECT queries to ignore *timestamp* and *computed* columns.  It would be easy to add additional exclusions for other specialty column types.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  some people dont realize these answers are given as a starting point not a plug-n-go.  This is a very useful script.  Thanks to @flerngobot and others for further suggestions

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT 'INSERT SomeOtherDB.dbo.table(column1,column2,etc.)
  SELECT ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Pk_Id) + ','
       + '''' + REPLACE(ProductName, '''', '''''') + ''','
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Fk_CompanyId) + ','
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Price) + ';'
FROM dbo.unspecified_table_name
WHERE Fk_CompanyId = 1;
```

Comment: How do you execute(run) those generated insert statement?

Comment: @J.W. Copy & paste? You could also do something like `SELECT @sql = @sql + N'INSERT ...;' FROM ...`.

Comment: Just a note to anyone using this: `select null +'x'` is `NULL`, so don't forget to initialise `@sql` to a non-null value, otherwise your whole statement will concatenate to `NULL`. Got me puzzled for 10 minutes.

Comment: Tanx, simple and useful :)

Comment: The coalesce function works well for string init in this scenario.

Answer (score 14):

I was actually able to accomplish this in SSMS without add ins or procs in just a few steps. 1) If you don't want the whole table, select the columns and records needed into a new table in the database: `SELECT col1, col2 ... INTO TempRecs`  2) Use the generate scripts feature of SSMS to generate the INSERT statements by right clicking the database (Tasks > Generate Scripts > Choose Objects > Select the temp table > Click Advanced button > Change "Types of data to script" to "Data only" > Finish). 3) Do a find and replace for the resultant INSERT statements on the temp table name to the desired import table name.

Comment: good solution, works if you have the write access on your source database. Wasn't the case for me.

Comment: This seems to be only solution if you need to also export VARBINARY data. SSMS Generate script knows how to correctly export these, but does not work with views (exports schema only despite the option to also export the data). Requires more steps, but does the job. Thanks.

Comment: This was a life saver. I was searching and searching and nothing worked. Finally this solution worked. The same task is a breeze on Oracle.

Comment: this is it. thanks

Answer (score 8):

In SSMS execute your sql query. From the result window select all cells and copy the values. Goto [below website](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) and there you can paste the copied data and generate sql scripts. You can also save results of query from SSMS as CSV file and import the csv file in [this](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) website.

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Comment: Nice site, works pretty well in most cases although more complex strings/large records didn't work for me when "copy with headers" from SSMS and pasting on the site. When I "save results as" to a .csv file and used upload it worked.

Comment: Will not handle 32 million rows.

Comment: What a briliant idea to copy customer records into "a website" so i can generate the script.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a view with your criteria and then export the view?

Comment: SSMS generate scripts will not export the data even if Data only is enforced.

Answer (score 5):

With the **DBeaver** client (which supports SQL Server) you can do a SELECT query with the records that you want and then select the resulting rows, right click and Copy as SQL, and you'll have the INSERT statement in your clipboard:

[image]

**HeidiSQL** also supports connecting to SQL Server and exporting selected rows (you can filter the rows in the SQL query itself, or retrieve all rows and select them in the data grid):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Import data doesn't have insert but I found very simple solution.

1. Create new table with same table structure of your selected existing table.
2. Use statement "Insert into NewTable select * from ExistingTable where Fk_CompanyId = 1"
3. Task -> Generate Script -> select your new table

Answer (score 2):

I created the following `procedure`:

```
if object_id('tool.create_insert', 'P') is null
begin
  exec('create procedure tool.create_insert as');
end;
go

alter procedure tool.create_insert(@schema    varchar(200) = 'dbo',
                                   @table     varchar(200),
                                   @where     varchar(max) = null,
                                   @top       int = null,
                                   @insert    varchar(max) output)
as
begin
  declare @insert_fields varchar(max),
          @select        varchar(max),
          @error         varchar(500),
          @query         varchar(max);

  declare @values table(description varchar(max));

  set nocount on;

  -- Get columns
  select @insert_fields = isnull(@insert_fields + ', ', '') + c.name,
         @select = case type_name(c.system_type_id)
                      when 'varchar' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      when 'datetime' then isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + ' isnull('''''''' + convert(varchar, ' + c.name + ', 121) + '''''''', ''null'')'
                      else isnull(@select + ' + '', '' + ', '') + 'isnull(cast(' + c.name + ' as varchar), ''null'')'
                    end
    from sys.columns c with(nolock)
         inner join sys.tables t with(nolock) on t.object_id = c.object_id
         inner join sys.schemas s with(nolock) on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
   where s.name = @schema
     and t.name = @table;

  -- If there's no columns...
  if @insert_fields is null or @select is null
  begin
    set @error = 'There''s no ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' inside the target database.';
    raiserror(@error, 16, 1);
    return;
  end;

  set @insert_fields = 'insert into ' + @schema + '.' + @table + '(' + @insert_fields + ')';

  if isnull(@where, '') <> '' and charindex('where', ltrim(rtrim(@where))) < 1
  begin
    set @where = 'where ' + @where;
  end
  else
  begin
    set @where = '';
  end;

  set @query = 'select ' + isnull('top(' + cast(@top as varchar) + ')', '') + @select + ' from ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' with (nolock) ' + @where;

  insert into @values(description)
  exec(@query);

  set @insert = isnull(@insert + char(10), '') + '--' + upper(@schema + '.' + @table);

  select @insert = @insert + char(10) + @insert_fields + char(10) + 'values(' + v.description + ');' + char(10) + 'go' + char(10)
    from @values v
   where isnull(v.description, '') <> '';
end;
go
```

Then you can use it that way:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @part   varchar(max),
        @start  int,
        @end    int;

set @start = 1;

exec tool.create_insert @schema = 'dbo',
                        @table = 'myTable',
                        @where  = 'Fk_CompanyId = 1',
                        @insert = @insert output;

-- Print one line to avoid the maximum 8000 characters problem
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @end = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @end = 0
  begin
    set @end = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @start, @end - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @end + 1, len(@insert) - @end + 1);
end;
```

The output would be something like that:

```
--DBO.MYTABLE
insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(1, 'AMX', 1, 10.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(2, 'ABC', 1, 11.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(3, 'APEX', 1, 12.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(4, 'AMX', 1, 10.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(5, 'ABC', 1, 11.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(6, 'APEX', 1, 12.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(7, 'AMX', 2, 10.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(8, 'ABC', 2, 11.00);
go

insert into dbo.myTable(Pk_Id, ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price)
values(9, 'APEX', 2, 12.00);
go
```

If you just want to get a range of rows, use the `@top` parameter as bellow:

```
declare @insert varchar(max),
        @part   varchar(max),
        @start  int,
        @end    int;

set @start = 1;

exec tool.create_insert @schema = 'dbo',
                        @table = 'myTable',
                        @top    = 100,
                        @insert = @insert output;

-- Print one line to avoid the maximum 8000 characters problem
while len(@insert) > 0
begin
  set @end = charindex(char(10), @insert);

  if @end = 0
  begin
    set @end = len(@insert) + 1;
  end;

  print substring(@insert, @start, @end - 1);
  set @insert = substring(@insert, @end + 1, len(@insert) - @end + 1);
end;
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I get an issue where both varchar values and datetime values are printed without surrounding quotes. Example: `values(18, Food processor, 106, 2017-12-07 15:17:35, 0, 1)`

Comment: @PeterB can you check if you're using `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle SQL Developer then it would be

```
select /*insert*/ * from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME = 'VALUE';
```

Run this as a script

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql and MySql workbench.
Here is a nice option.

1. Write your select query and execute it
2. You'll see the Export button
3. [image: List item]
4. Click on it and give a filename and in "Save as Type" you'll see "SQL Insert Statements"

This will give you insert statements

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Navicat

1. Filter your data in table or write your query

[image: First Step]

2. Select row and right click it > Copy AS > Select "Insert Statement" or "Update Statement"

[image: Second Step]

3. Paste in New Query in MS SQL Server Management Studio or other IDE

[image: Third Step]

Answer (score 0):

It can be generate using the follow method:

```
    select ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price from [Table] where Fk_CompanyId = 1
```

In the Result section, use mouse to right click, from the menu select Generate script As, INSERT:

```
    SET DATEFORMAT ymd
    
    INSERT INTO [Table] (ProductName, Fk_CompanyId, Price) VALUES
    (N'AMX', 1, 10),
    (N'ABC', 1, 11),
    (N'APEX', 1, 12),
    (N'AMX', 1, 10),
    (N'ABC', 1, 11),
    (N'APEX', 1, 12)
    GO
```

Comment: I have no such option in SSMS v 18.3. Tried results to file, results to grid, and results to text.  Do you have an extension installed?

Comment: Ah, It occur to me i have a 'dforge sql complete free edition' installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Redgate**

Select rows you want

Click *Script as INSERT*

It will automatically generate insert statement for selected rows

[image]