# Copy only single record from each table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy tables from one database / server to another database/server. The requirement is, while copying tables to the destination, I just need only one record from each table(as a sample record).

Have tried data migration options but none of them gives the option to limit the number of records.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: select top 1 * from tableA ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Hi, I don't have any query for that. What I tried was to perform it using import/ export or through SSIS. But at there, they have options like either structure or both structure as well as data. what I am looking for is to copy the structure and only one record (single row) from each table.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that this is answering fully the question but it is a start

```
SELECT ' SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.NAME) + '; '
FROM   sys.tables t
   JOIN sys.schemas s
     ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U'
```

This will generate a select query for each table in your system (user tables).

If you need to excute the statements you can try this (not convenient if you have many tables though):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT @sql+=' SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.NAME) + '.' +   QUOTENAME(t.NAME) + '; '
FROM   sys.tables t
   JOIN sys.schemas s
     ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U';

Exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Other solution would be to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560713/generate-insert-script-for-selected-records)