# Create Script for top 100 values from a table with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to generate a script with SQL Server Management Studio for only the values ​​in the table. I only want the top 100. I already found a way to script everything by going to Task -> Generate Scripts...

[image: Generate scripts]

I chose data only but it returns the whole table:

[image: Generate script options]

I only need the top 100 rows. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to script the data anyway? Is this some kind of migration scenario? Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560713/generate-insert-script-for-selected-records) resolve your issue?

Comment: Script the whole table and edit the script to keep only 100 rows? Use `select ... into ...` to copy the `top 100` rows into another table and script that, then edit the table name in the script?

Comment: the table rows are to large to script. im talking about milion records. I need only the first 100 of them.

Comment: So you're asking how to use a specific tool to script _rows_ that are too large for it to handle? That would rule out my second suggestion of copying the "first" 100 rows to a separate table and scripting _that_ table.

Comment: How should the query look like? The script looks like this but it is much bigger:
`USE [DB]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([name], [surname] ) VALUES ('peter', 'mcdonald')
GO
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([name], [surname] ) VALUES ('person2', 'mcdonald')
GO
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([name], [surname] ) VALUES ('person3', 'mcdonald')
GO
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Person] ([name], [surname] ) VALUES ('person4', 'mcdonald')
GO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a INSERT script for the TOP 100 recordsets in a first step and execute the generated script in a second step you can try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #target;

CREATE TABLE #source ( value1 INT, value2 VARCHAR(100) );
CREATE TABLE #target ( value1 INT, value2 VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT INTO #source
VALUES (10, 'A100'), (10, 'A101'), (10, 'A102'), (10, 'A103'), (20, 'B100'), (20, 'B101')

-- STEP 1: GENERATE SCRIPT

SELECT TOP 3 sql = 'INSERT INTO #target(value1, value2) VALUES' + '(' + CAST(value1 AS VARCHAR(100)) + ', ''' + value2 + ''');'
FROM #source
ORDER BY value2 DESC

-- STEP 2: EXEC GENERATED SCRIPT

INSERT INTO #target(value1, value2) VALUES(20, 'B101');
INSERT INTO #target(value1, value2) VALUES(20, 'B100');
INSERT INTO #target(value1, value2) VALUES(10, 'A103');

-- RESULT:

SELECT * FROM #target;
```

The cast and recast to VARCHAR may be exhausting if you have a lot of columns to handle.
If it is not necessary to create a interim script it would be easier this way:

```
INSERT INTO #target(value1, value2)
SELECT TOP 3 value1, value2 FROM #source;
```

Comment: This is maybe one way of a solution, but it will be a hell of a job to script tables with more then 40 columns...

Comment: I would imagine the goal of most is to avoid having to write all the casts, commas, and escaped quotes.