# Create an UPDATE statement for every row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update a table on one server with data from a table on another server. The tables have the same columns and I just want to sync the data. I have earlier made a script that creates insert statements for these tables (put out a question to SO and answered it myself...) but the seemingly simpler task of creating `UPDATE` statements now eludes me. Maybe because I'm just back from holiday.

For reference, here's my "INSERT question": [Creating "Not Exists"/Insert Into Statements - Stumped by nothing (NULL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320564/creating-not-exists-insert-into-statements-stumped-by-nothing-null/)

I'm trying to use my `INSERT` statements code but I'm either not getting multiple rows or just getting hard-to-debug error messages (Error close to NULL)

So, what I want to do is creating statements like this, one for each row in the table:

```
UPDATE WorkflowError 
   SET [ErrorDescription] = 'Error creating email' 
 WHERE [TargetSystem]='Fullmaktsnoden' 
   AND  [ErrorCode]='999' 
   AND  [ErrorText]='Error creating email' 
   AND [ErrorDescription] IS NULL
```

I could use some general pointers like `"Since you're now creating UPDATE statements instead of INSERT you need to think about..."`

This is a table used for integration of several systems. We "collect" messages we get from other systems and record them in ErrorDescription. If it's too long or misleading we put a shorter explanation in Errortext to show for the user. (in this example I happened to use the same text, "error creating email", but in the real system the error description we get is much longer)

One try is a code like this:

```
USE FullmaktsnodenProcess
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @QUOTED_DATA VARCHAR(MAX),
        @DOES_EXIST VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL_KOD VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
        @FIRST_COL INT,
        @LAST_COL INT,
        @THE_COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX)


/* INPUT DATA */
SELECT @TABLE_NAME = 'WorkflowError'
SELECT @FIRST_COL = 2 -- First column for Exists check
SELECT @LAST_COL = 4 -- Last column for Exists check
SELECT @THE_COLUMN = 'ErrorDescription'
/* */

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE('+COLUMN_NAME+','''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''','''+'NULL'''+''+')+'',''+'
     FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE table_name = @TABLE_NAME AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = @THE_COLUMN
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=SUBSTRING(@QUOTED_DATA,1,LEN(@QUOTED_DATA)-5)

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA

SELECT @DOES_EXIST=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' ['+ COLUMN_NAME +']='' + ', 'ISNULL('''''''' + REPLACE('+COLUMN_NAME+','''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''','''+'NULL'''+''+')+'' AND '
     FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE table_name = @TABLE_NAME AND 
     ordinal_position BETWEEN @FIRST_COL AND @LAST_COL
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @DOES_EXIST


SELECT @SQL_KOD='SELECT ''UPDATE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' +  QUOTENAME(@THE_COLUMN) + ' = ' + @QUOTED_DATA + ' WHERE ' + @DOES_EXIST + @THE_COLUMN + ' IS NULL'''

SELECT @SQL_KOD

EXECUTE (@SQL_KOD)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO
```

---

Trying to execute @SQL_KOD gives: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'."

From test run, with EXECUTE (@SQL_KOD) commented out:

```
@QUOTED_DATA = ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorDescription,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')

@DOES_EXIST = [TargetSystem]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(TargetSystem,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorCode]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorCode,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorText]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorText,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND 

@SQL_KOD = SELECT 'UPDATE WorkflowError SET [ErrorDescription] = ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorDescription,'''','''''') + '''','NULL') WHERE [TargetSystem]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(TargetSystem,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorCode]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorCode,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorText]=' + ISNULL('''' + REPLACE(ErrorText,'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND ErrorDescription IS NULL'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195512/discussion-on-question-by-tommy-petersson-create-an-update-statement-for-every-r).

Comment: Next step: This code creates the desired end result, now it's just to create the code that creates this code...: `SELECT 'UPDATE WorkflowError SET [ErrorDescription] =''' + ISNULL(REPLACE([ErrorDescription],'''','''''') + '''','NULL') +
' WHERE [TargetSystem]=''' + ISNULL(REPLACE([TargetSystem],'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorCode]=''' + ISNULL(REPLACE([ErrorCode],'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND  [ErrorText]=''' + ISNULL(REPLACE([ErrorText],'''','''''') + '''','NULL')+' AND '
 + ' [ErrorDescription] IS NULL '
Update_Script FROM WorkflowError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fit the bill. Qutation marks in data are now correctly doubled and the end result is one UPDATE statement for each row in the table, as I wanted. As I mentioned, reading from information_schema.columns is unnecessary when I'm here just working with one known column, but maybe when I'm modyfying this script for another table it's not so...

```
USE FullmaktsnodenProcess
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @QUOTED_DATA VARCHAR(MAX),
        @DOES_EXIST VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL_KOD VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
        @FIRST_COL INT,
        @LAST_COL INT,
        @THE_COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX)


/* INPUT DATA */
SELECT @TABLE_NAME = 'WorkflowError'
SELECT @FIRST_COL = 2 -- First column for Exists check
SELECT @LAST_COL = 4 -- Last column for Exists check
SELECT @THE_COLUMN = 'ErrorDescription'
/* */

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' ISNULL(REPLACE('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+','''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''','''+'NULL'''+''+')+'',''+'
     FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE table_name = @TABLE_NAME AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = @THE_COLUMN
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=SUBSTRING(@QUOTED_DATA,1,LEN(@QUOTED_DATA)-5)

--SELECT @QUOTED_DATA

SELECT @DOES_EXIST=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) +'='''''' + ', 'ISNULL(REPLACE('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+','''''''','''''''''''') + '''''''','''+'NULL'''+''+')+'' AND '
     FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE table_name = @TABLE_NAME AND 
     ordinal_position BETWEEN @FIRST_COL AND @LAST_COL
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

-- SELECT @DOES_EXIST

SELECT @SQL_KOD='SELECT ''UPDATE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' +  QUOTENAME(@THE_COLUMN) + ' = ' + ''''''' + ' + @QUOTED_DATA + ' + ' + ''' WHERE ' + @DOES_EXIST + @THE_COLUMN + ' IS NULL ' + ''' Update_Script ' + 'FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME

-- SELECT @SQL_KOD

EXECUTE (@SQL_KOD)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO
```