# Copy rows from server1.database.table to server2.database.table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a use case where I want to be able to insert certain data rows from one database environment to another.

I have the grasp for how to copy from one database to another while on the same server by:

```
INSERT DB1.dbo.DataValue(DateStamp, ItemId, Value)
SELECT DateStamp, ItemId, Value 
FROM DB2dbo.DataValue AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DB1.dbo.DataValue AS d
WHERE DateStamp = t.DateStamp
AND ItemId = t.ItemId);
```

But I am unsure about how to do it over databases hosted on different servers. Ignoring the security aspect for now as well. Database version is:
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8  
 
 Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can't do cross database queries Azure SQL Database, let alone Cross Server queries. You would, however, have to use the same method as a cross database solution, and use an `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE`.

Comment: Yes thank you! I then utilised a script to copy data for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

To copy data between different servers you can use:

1. Linked servers (NOT supported in Azure. thanks to a comment)
2. Any ETL-tool,e.g. SQL Server Integration Services

Comment: Linked servers aren't supported in Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: Have you looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526461/converting-select-results-into-insert-script-sql-server. It has a highly voted answer that mending some manual steps but it will definitely work for without needing too much effort.