# how to generate insert data script from #temp tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

In DB I have #temp tables with data and I need to generate insert Scripts (for all data).

How it can be done ?  I right clicked on tempDB and selected > Tasks > Generate Scripts but I can't select #temp tables to generate script (they are not avaialble to select).

how I can geneate Insert script from #temp tables I m using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: can you transfer it into a new table using `SELECT * INTO` and then generate a script?

Comment: @ughai, do you mean create a physical table ?

Comment: yes and remove it after generation of scripts

Comment: it will be much time consuming, I will have to manually create many tables. any better way please ?

Comment: you don't need to manually create any table. you just need to have a single `SELECT` for each #temp table like this `SELECT * INTO Tbl1 FROM #temp1`. the table is created automatically. look it up

Answer (score 4):

You can insert your query results into sql table (temporary table , it will be created **automatically** ):

```
SELECT * INTO myTempTable FROM (query results)
```

e.g : `SELECT * INTO myTempTable FROM user  where condition`

A table named  `myTempTable`  will be created inside schema `dbo` 
Then click on database click :

`Tasks > Generate Scripts`

and you choose the table `myTempTable`

Comment: Small hint: Don't use `#` as a prefix for you tablename. Yoiu wo'nt be able to find your table when using `generate Scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Another best way to do it just bit faster but longer.

Use SqlPubWiz

Just go:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4

and run and fill required information regarding log in into database and choose your database and get your whole database script and find the table's insert script that you wanted in your saved script file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query batch for generating scripts for `temp tables` and you can select the rows based on the conditions. I have got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029743/311255). In the original source, the Author created `Stored Procedure` for generating scripts. I have formatted and modified for declaring `TableName` with Condition. You need to run this query batch in `tempdb` with your `#temp table name`. Thanks to [Neeraj Prasad Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768223/neeraj-prasad-sharma).

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Dbo.#Temp where 1 = 1'

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @WithStrINdex AS INT
DECLARE @WhereStrINdex AS INT
DECLARE @INDExtouse AS INT

DECLARE @SchemaAndTAble VARCHAR(270)
DECLARE @Schema_name VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @Table_name VARCHAR(240)
DECLARE @Condition VARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @WithStrINdex = 0
SELECT @WithStrINdex = CHARINDEX('WITH', @Query), @WhereStrINdex = CHARINDEX('WHERE', @Query)

IF(@WithStrINdex != 0)
    SELECT @INDExtouse = @WithStrINdex
ELSE
    SELECT @INDExtouse = @WhereStrINdex

SELECT @SchemaAndTAble  =  LEFT(@Query, @INDExtouse - 1) 
SELECT @SchemaAndTAble = LTRIM(RTRIM(@SchemaAndTAble))

SELECT @Schema_name = LEFT(@SchemaAndTAble, CHARINDEX('.', @SchemaAndTAble ) - 1)
,@Table_name  =  SUBSTRING(@SchemaAndTAble, CHARINDEX('.', @SchemaAndTAble ) + 1, LEN(@SchemaAndTAble))
,@CONDITION = SUBSTRING(@Query, @WhereStrINdex + 6, LEN(@Query))--27+6


DECLARE @COLUMNS TABLE([Row_number] SMALLINT, Column_Name VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @CONDITIONS AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Total_Rows AS SMALLINT
DECLARE @Counter AS SMALLINT

DECLARE @ComaCol AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ComaCol = '', @Counter = 1, @CONDITIONS = '' 

print @Schema_name
print @Table_name

INSERT INTO @COLUMNS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) [Count] ,COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema_name
AND TABLE_NAME = @Table_name 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('SYNCDESTINATION','PENDINGSYNCDESTINATION' ,'SKUID','SALECREDITEDTO')

SELECT @Total_Rows = COUNT(*) FROM @COLUMNS
SELECT @Table_name = '['+@Table_name+']'
SELECT @Schema_name = '['+@Schema_name+']'

WHILE (@Counter< = @Total_Rows )
BEGIN 
    SELECT @ComaCol =  @ComaCol + ' ['+Column_Name+'],' FROM @COLUMNS
    Where [Row_number] = @Counter

    SELECT @CONDITIONS = @CONDITIONS+ ' + CASE WHEN ['+Column_Name+'] IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE '''''''' + 
                    REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),['+Column_Name+']) ,'''''''','''')
                    +'''''''' END +'+''','''
                    FROM @COLUMNS WHERE [Row_number] = @Counter

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END

SELECT @CONDITIONS = RIGHT(@CONDITIONS, LEN(@CONDITIONS) -2)

SELECT @CONDITIONS = LEFT(@CONDITIONS, LEN(@CONDITIONS) -4)

SELECT @ComaCol =  SUBSTRING (@ComaCol, 0, LEN(@ComaCol))

SELECT @CONDITIONS =  '''INSERT INTO ' + @Schema_name + '.' + @Table_name + '(' + @ComaCol + ')' +' VALUES( '+'''' + '+' + @CONDITIONS
SELECT @CONDITIONS = @CONDITIONS + '+' + ''')'''

SELECT @CONDITIONS =  'SELECT' + @CONDITIONS + 'FROM' + @Schema_name + '.' + @Table_name + ' WITH(NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @Condition
PRINT(@CONDITIONS)
EXEC(@CONDITIONS)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to right click on database and click on

```
Tasks -> Generate Scripts
```

now you are having a popup screen go to next click

```
Select specific database objects
```

now select your table from Tables option and click next now you have Advanced button there click on it.

You will have another small popup screen available choose
Types of data to script and select

```
Data only
```

click OK and don't forget to see the path as file name where your script save carefully.

Now click Next and again Next your script is ready with the data.

Comment: I m doing same but clicking on Specific 'database objects' I don't see my temp tables. Are you saying I will see my #temp tables clicking this option ?

Comment: You can also do it by copy your temp table's data to new table and get script of the new table.

Comment: You can also use SSMS Tools pack just go http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9 and see how it is working!

Comment: Ok than you can get your solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script

Comment: this is for PostgreSQL, not going to work for SQL Server