# Auto-generate insert statements in SQL Server based on criteria of existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, one of which uses 1 of the other 2's table's int PK as their FK. I'm not 100% familiar with SQL Server, but based on existing data and vis a where condition, is there a way to create insert statements for all 3 tables?

EDIT: One of these tables also has a blob, to make things (possibly) more complex.

Comment: Have you tried looking into  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818796/generate-sql-insert-script-from-excel-worksheet

Comment: @mhn I haven't, but I forgot to mention that one of these tables also has a blob. Using the Excel method (assuming I just copy and paste data from a select query) would it still be possible?

Comment: Generating sql scripts is pretty straight forward in SQL Server. You can follow steps at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065357/how-to-generate-an-insert-script-for-an-existing-sql-server-table-that-includes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are looking for a trigger function, your INSERT statement will have the new.ID record and update the other two tables based on the ID of the first one.

Another option is that you use a stored procedure to insert the data in the 3 columns, where you set a variable for each info of the table and at the end to read the new.ID assigned in the tables and updates the 1st table.

We can help you a lot more if you tell us more details of your 3 tables, is it a customers table, products table etc.