# Easy data initialization of CodeFirst database via XML or similar format

Tags: xml, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Has anyone published a generic database initializer capable of taking an XML file (or other file representation) of database contents and using it to initialize a code-first database in the Seed method?

I'm thinking of something that uses Reflection to populate the database. I realize there is a lot of fun to be head with FK relationships, but if such a tool existed, especially if it was bi-directional, it would be very handy. Unfortunately my google-fu is failing me.

Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something...I've got an awful lot of init code I could throw away...

Comment: Hmm.... this approach is specifically called **code-first**, e.g. you don't need any XML config or anything - you just code it ... seems a bit "off" in that context to want to introduce some config XML again...

Comment: Its called code first. Its not called "Destroy your data every time you make a tiny schema change first". For some projects, that's not a problem. For others, a way of preserving data *while still writing code first and not swapping to schema first* would be a serious benefit. I do take your point about XML. I'd be happy with a data aware T4 template that auto generated EF insert code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the actual data itself?  In that case, XML and reflection would be overkill.  Just put the data in the DB, and the re-export your INSERT statements:

[What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)

Then, in your Seed methods (or InitializeDatabase()), read in your exported file and use context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand().

Comment: Thanks - that script looks perfect to re-seed the data.