# How to copy azure tables with entries

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am looking to copy some lookup tables that are currently on windows azure.  I do not believe trhere is a way to do this through sql server management studio so I'm wondering the best way to do this other than scripting them out by hand

Comment: Are you looking to copy tables in SQL Database or Windows Azure table storage?

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use the [SQL Database Migration Wizard (SQLAzureMW)](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) for any task involving moving data from and to SQL Azure. This tool knows what is and what isn't supported in SQL Azure and will be more effective than manually creating the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Select into will create and copy the table but will not create indexes or constraints.

[INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

In SSMS your can right click a table and select generate to create a script.  Then you can edit the table and other names and run the script.

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is not supported in SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here, it was easier than I could have hoped!

[What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: You will need to change the **Script for the database engine type** option to **SQL Azure Database**