# command to generate insert and update script in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is there any command is sql server 2005 which generate insert/update script?

I need same output which we get by using this step:

- Right click on table then select "Script Table As" => "Insert to" or "Update to" then output media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some thread about this in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table).

For example you can use a 3rd party, well written stored procedure called **sp_generate_inserts**. (Or you can write your own solution too based on this idea)

It is not exactly what you need, because it is generally for scription existing data, but from the script you can find some idea how to do it, or you can check the parameter options for the SP.

Find it here: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi: [sp_generate_inserts](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts_2005.txt)