# Execution result of SQL Server procedure as script

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I need to write procedure `Textprocedure (Table_txt varchar(200))` that scans data from table My_table
For ex: I have table

```
My_table (Id  int,  Name varchar(200))
```

**I need result of procedure execution like output text (script) like**

```
DELETE FROM My_table 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (1, 'Tropico') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (2, 'Bus') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (4, 'Africa') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (8, 'Arrival')
```

Can I do it with procedure? I do

```
CREATE TABLE My_table (Id  int,  Name varchar(200))

DELETE FROM My_table 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (1, 'Tropico') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (2, 'Bus') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (4, 'Africa') 
INSERT INTO My_table (Id, Name) values (8, 'Arrival')

ALTER PROCEDURE Textprocedure (@Table_txt varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Id1 NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @Result = ''
SELECT @Result = 'INSERT INTO '+ CAST(@Table_txt AS NVARCHAR(250)) + --@Result 
+'() values ' + CAST([name] AS NVARCHAR(250)) + ' ' FROM My_table --where Id<5
PRINT (@Result)
END
GO

EXEC Textprocedure My_table
```

My output: `INSERT INTO My_table() values Arrival` 
But I need result in many rows. Can I do cycle? And I need print table params like id, name? But how can I pick them?

Comment: What should Table_txt param do?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: OK. I would show you.

Comment: In generating the insert statements I suggest using the `QuoteName()` function around the table name, and you'll need single quotes around the value since it's a varchar. You can escape single quotes with another single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Check this to generate insert statements:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/982576/590741

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt

Comment: PRINT is what I need to use

Comment: But this is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql with parameters then print or return the result.

Comment: I would try. Thanks [b]Amirreza Keshavarz[/b]