# How to backup and restore a SQL Server database in an ASP.NET app and get the backup file from a web page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

I have an ASP.NET web app on a shared hosting server and a SQL Server database on a database server. I would like to backup and restore the database programmatically in the web app where the site owner can download/upload the backup file from a browser. Looking for a solution which works in medium trust. I think SMO (shared management objects libraries) requires full trust and not sure if it even meets my needs. Writing files on the database server, using a control panel or SSMS is not an option.

While I might be able to write SQL Scripts to do all this work, it's going to take some time to have it work reliably for any database. I was wondering if these kind of scripts or a suitable library is available.

Comment: Without a way to write to an accessible location on the database server machine you will be unable to run the `BACKUP DATABASE` command. You'll have to speak with your webhost if you want a proper backup file. The only option is to dump all of the data using `SELECT` commands, and that isn't going to be pretty.

Comment: I need this to be done programmatically and the host won't provide access to the database file system. I know it's not pretty, hence my question. Looking for someone who went through a similar situation and created a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the shared hosting, and the desire to get backups on-demand, you may need to actually run a SQL query that essentially iterates all the metadata and raw data and generates a bunch of SQL INSERT statements.

The good news is, this is a well-solved problem. See this question: [What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table) or just Google "SQL script generator". If you look at some of the open source projects out there, that might be the easiest code to integrate.

With the *caveat*, it might be worth giving your hosting company a call and just explaining your needs, especially if they are a smaller company. I used to be Dir of Engineering for a small web hosting company and we'd setup ad hoc solutions for folks all the time.