# Generate data seeding script using PowerShell and SSMS

Tags: sql, powershell, t-sql, ssms

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316313/9918730) I found a solution for the manual creation of the data seeding script. The manual solution allows me to select for which tables I want to generate the *inserts*

I would like to know if there is an option to run the same process via PowerShell?

So far I have managed how to create a SQL script which creates the Database **schema** seeder:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "(localdb)\mssqlLocalDb"  

$dbs=$s.Databases 

#$dbs["HdaRoot"].Script() 
$dbs["HdaRoot"].Script() | Out-File C:\sql-seeding\HdaRoot.sql  

#Generate script for all tables

foreach ($tables in $dbs["HdaRoot"].Tables) 
{
    $tables.Script() + "`r GO `r " | out-File C:\sql-seeding\HdaRoot.sql  -Append
}
```

however is there any similar way to generate the **data** seeding script?

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you can change this to run as pure powershell?

Comment: I want to use PowerShell to run the Data Seeding feature from SSMS and generate the SQL script

Comment: LoadWithPartialName is now [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadwithpartialname?view=netframework-4.7.2). The recommended solution for PowerShell V3 and up is to use the Add-Type cmdlet.

Comment: Ok, I'll bear that in mind however is there an option to build similar script for the creation of the Seeding scripts for each table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [SMO scripter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0). This will allow you to script the table creates as well as `INSERT` statements for the data within the tables.

In my example I'm directly targeting TempDB and defining an array of table names I want to script out rather than scripting out every table.

Scripter has a lot of options available, so I've only done a handful in this example - the important one for this task is `Options.ScriptData`. Without it you'll just get the schema scripts that you're already getting.

The EnumScript method at the end does the actual work of generating the scripts, outputting, and appending the script to the file designated in the options.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

## target file
$outfile = 'f:\scriptOutput.sql' 

## target server
$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "localhost"  

## target database
$db = $s.databases['tempdb'] 

## array of tables that we want to check
$tables = @('Client','mytable','tablesHolding')

## new Scripter object
$tableScripter = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter')($s) 

##define options for the scripter
$tableScripter.Options.AppendToFile = $True
$tableScripter.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
$tableScripter.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
$tableScripter.Options.Indexes = $True
$tableScripter.Options.ScriptData = $True
$tableScripter.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
$tableScripter.Options.filename = $outfile

## build out the script for each table we defined earlier
foreach ($table in $tables) 
{
    $tableScripter.enumscript(@($db.tables[$table])) #enumscript expects an array. this is ugly, but it gives it what it wants.
}
```

Comment: I want to generate data seeding script only. It also generates the schema seeder script. How disable the 2nd thing?

Comment: ok I found in the documentation. Need to add `$tableScripter.Options.ScriptSchema = $False`

Comment: Your solution seems to work. I've [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017#system-requirements) that SMO is a NuGet package. I'm just wondering does this script require to have SSMS installed on the machine or only .net framework 4.0> to run it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to have SSMS installed for it to work.