# Get all the row data with select statement in codebehind C# using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem.
what i want to achieve is to get all rows of a table and put them in a string with comma between each value. The result should be a scriptfile to get all of the rowdata in the table.

**For so far:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string ConString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=USR;Integrated Security=True";
    foreach (string itemtablename in TableNames())
    {
        Schema schema = new Schema();
        schema.TableName = itemtablename; //the name of the table

        //int i = 0;
        string queryvalues = "select * from " + itemtablename;
        SqlConnection conValues = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        using (conValues)
        {
            conValues.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdSchemaValues = new SqlCommand(queryvalues, conValues);
            SqlDataReader readerSchemaValues = cmdSchemaValues.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dataTable = readerSchemaValues.GetSchemaTable();

            //builder.AppendLine("INSERT INTO " + itemtablename);
            //builder.AppendLine(" VALUES (");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string rowValues= dataTable.Rows[i].ToString() + ",";
               
                builder.Append(rowValues);
            }
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\script.txt", builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Warning, statements like `string queryvalues = "select * from " + itemtablename;` are **wide** open to injection.

Comment: What is this trying to do? Generate a script or actually insert data? Why not export the data to a CSV file and import it as needed? A single `'` in one of those fields could result in an invalid script or worse, allow script injection attacks

Comment: Just need to create only the insert value script with data form the database. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the actual _problem_ here? You've shown some code. You've described a goal. What's missing is any discussion of your precise difficulty. Where does your code fall short of that goal currently? Please describe the current behaviour of the code, and give an example of exactly what you wanted instead.

Comment: Have you considered saving the data as XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
foreach(DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
{
    builder.AppendLine("INSERT INTO " + itemtablename + "(" + string.Join(", ", datatable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray()).Trim().TrimEnd(","));
    builder.AppendLine("VALUES ('" + string.Join("', '", row.ItemArray).Trim().TrimEnd('\'').Trim().TrimEnd(',') + "')")
}

string script = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If "generating the insert script for data present in the table" is the objective then you can try using the SQL Server Management Studio to do that. It has been discussed in other [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table) as well.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants to be able to automate that, or do it at scale for multiple tables?

Comment: I want to create the insert values part from codebehind.