# Generate a table based on another table structure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

What i m looking for is to duplicate a table.

The complicate part is to get the table script (which includes also the relationships) with a query and not using the Script Table as - CREATE To.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do this when there is an available function in SSMS

Comment: i want to use SSIS

Comment: Can you use Powershell https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785119/14868997

Answer (score 0):

This will suffice for columns, datatypes and nulability:

```
select top 0 *
into destination_table
from source_table
```

For keys, constraints, indexes, triggers and other stuff you'll still have to use information_schema/sys tables

Comment: There are many use cases where this will fail

Comment: Interesting. The only case I have in my mind to avoid this is creating identical `rowversion`s in case the `top` number is positive. Could you elaborate?

Comment: it was a while ago for a specific examples --- as I remember it you could have the default varchar sizes set to one thing and a select would always use the default size in creating the table unless there was data that was larger in the select