# Building a data migration tool to migrate data from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sqlbulkcopy, efcore.bulkextensions

I need to build a C# console application to migrate data from MySql to SQL Server. This would be run for runtime. I can not use other third-party tools since table schemas are different from MySql and SQL Server.

I have to generate destination entities from the source table which are different by table names and column names.

Note: I have a table called `Customer`. This table will have a couple of navigation properties. I need to add these navigation properties (save the entities of navigation) when bulk inserts the customer.

To save the data what would be the ideal way as bulk insertion? I tried with `EFCore.BulkExtensions` seems like it is not ideal since it does not set the Id after insertion as EF Core does.

I won't use `SqlBulkCopy` since there are plenty of tables to migrate.

Comment: What does this have to do with Entity Framework? It's an ORM, not an ETL or migration tool and *CAN'T* handle schema differences. Data migration between different schemas isn't trivial and can't be done automagically. You'll have to move data to different tables or columns, split or combine columns etc. You may have to move tables in a specific order, or disable constraints and indexes while moving data. SQL Server's ETL tool is SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). Once you create a flow you can run it periodically using SQL Server Agent

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know EF is an ORM. I am not asking here about the automatic tools, I have already wrote it can not be done by automatic tools. I want to build C# console application. In here my question what would be good way to save entities which has lots of navigation entities.

Comment: If you do, you know EF is completely inappropriate and has *no* features that could help. There are no entities in data movement. ORMs are meant to give the impression of working with in-memory application objects instead of tables and rows. They work by loading individual objects instead of working with the stream of data you need. What you want though has *no* objects or behavior, it's tables, rows and transformations.

Comment: `good way to save entities which has lots of navigation entities.` not with an ORM. You don't have one entity with lots of relations, you have *thousands* of them. The fast way is to *use* SqlBulkCopy to load lookup data first (eg categories, products) in a fast stream before you load the rows that depend on them. The difference is *several* orders of magnitude and getting worse the more data you have. 10K rows is no data at all, but  moving 10K objects and their dependencies can be more than 10K times slower, especially if those operations result in blocking.

Comment: You can scaffold both databases by `linq2db` and transfer tables one by one. Navigation properties is just references to other tables. You can preserve IDs from original database and transfer of one table should be simple: `destDB.BulkCopy(sourceDb.GetTable<SomeTable>().Select(t = config.Map<SomeTableDest>(t)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the need for reusability (is it a one off usage?), the need for scalability (is it a huge database with millions upon millions or rows?), you have several solutions. All solutions will follow the same process though.

1. Read the data from the source database
2. Optionally Transform it if the structure is different between source and target
3. Push the data to the target database.

You could use EF to perform the read / write operations, but it might just be a lot faster to just write the SQL yourself since you won't need as much scaffolding.
SQL Server also gives you tools to generate the insert statements to save you some time writing them. See [What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)